# Why use an ES6 Map instead of a plain javascript object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If we can make key/value pairs with plain javascript objects, then what is the reason to use the new ES6 [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object?

When should I use one and when the other? Is Map limited to values or can it contain functions as well?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map vs Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. Anything can be used as a key in a map.
2. Maps are ordered, and that allows for iteration.

Combining 1 and 2, when you iterate over a map, you'll get a useful array of key-value pairs!

Check out the [`map.prototype.forEach()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach).

Source: Another good question/answer [exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript). Worth marking this one as a duplicate.

***Update:***
Adding to this answer to address the question directly:
You should use a map whenever you need to associate things together or preserve insertion order (common data structures need this).

You can use an object when you don't need to do this, but they just do different things.

***Update 2:***
OP asked if functions are okay too. Yes, because values can be functions too! Check it out:

```js
let x = new Map();
let y = () => {
  console.log('derp');
}
x.set(y, "HI");
console.log(x.get(y)); // will log "HI"
```

For more info, check out the source of this quote, in a great chapter of [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/01_values.html):
*"Every value has a type that determines its role. There are six basic types of values in JavaScript: numbers, strings, Booleans, objects, functions, and undefined values."*

Also, the main differences between Map and Object, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), under the header "**Objects and Maps Compared**":

1. An Object has a prototype, so there are default keys in the map. However, this can be bypassed using map = Object.create(null).
2. The keys of an Object are Strings, where they can be any value for a Map.
3. You can get the size of a Map easily while you have to manually keep track of size for an Object.

Again, the keys can be *any value*!

Comment: Anything? Even functions?

Comment: Could you explain me what this line does? `let y = () => {`

Comment: Sure! That's an ES6 Arrow function. It's a shorter syntax for declaring a function, that also does something called lexical binding of the function's `this` value. It's related to some popular coffeescript syntax. Google around a bit. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 14):

- Maps are ordered.
- Map keys do not have to be strings

Comment: can you expand on the ordered-ness. does it give anything more than what we can do with just iterating over the current keys of a javascript object

Comment: @amdixon — Yes. It guarantees you will get the same order every time.

Comment: Yup. Maps are iterable, maintain order on iteration, and have size instead of length!

Comment: @Bergi: But only for non-index keys. Iterating over a map is a bit more predictable.