# Getting and setting values in a map in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to get and set the value of a map like an object in JavaScript. I was successfully able to do that. Still I have a doubt whether this is the right way to go about it or will my code break at any point of time?

```
    m = new Map();
    Map {}
    > m.set('a', 1) //set value
    Map { 'a' => 1 }
    > m.get('a') //get it
    1
    > m['b'] = 2 //try using more convenient [] notation
    2
    > m['b'] //it works!
    2
```

Though this works fine for this particular scenario or other scenarios, is there a scenario where getting a map using m['b'] would fail?

Comment: It doesn't 'work'. Maps are objects, and like any object you can add properties whenever you want, but it's not the same as using `.set`. If your keys are all strings, just use a plain object instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Map vs Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

They're not the same. When you're using bracket notation (or dot notation) rather than `.set` and `.get`, you're using the `Map` as a *plain object*, not a `Map`. For example, if you try accessing `b` afterwards using `m.get`, it won't work, because `b` is not a *key in the map*, but a *property of the `m` object*:

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set('a', 1) //set value
m['b'] = 2 //try using more convenient [] notation
m['b'] //it works!
console.log(m.get('b')) // ...or not
```

You *can* use a `Map` as an object like that, and get/set arbitrary properties rather than `.get` and `.set` methods, but it'll be pretty confusing. Better to use a plain object when appropriate, or to use a `Map` with `.get` and `.set` methods - but don't mix the two syntaxes.

Comment: 'b' also won't show up in any of the iterator methods like `.keys`

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, I tried all the possibilities and you are right. It does not treat b as a key but just as property of m