# Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-generics, union-types, es6-map

I would like to use Map instead of object map to declare some keys and values. But Typescript doesn't seem to support index types for ES6 Map, is that correct and are there any workarounds?

Additionally, I would like to make the values type-safe as well so that each entry in the map has the correct type for the value corresponding to the key.

Here is some pseudo-code that describes what I am trying to achieve:

```
type Keys = 'key1' | 'key2';

type  Values = {
  'key1': string;
  'key2': number;
}

/** Should display missing entry error */
const myMap = new Map<K in Keys, Values[K]>([
  ['key1', 'error missing key'],
]);

/** Should display wrong value type error for 'key2' */
const myMap = new Map<K in Keys, Values[K]>([
  ['key1', 'okay'],
  ['key2', 'error: this value should be number'],
]);

/** Should pass */
const myMap = new Map<K in Keys, Values[K]>([
  ['key1', 'all good'],
  ['key2', 42],
]);
```

Edit: more code that partially describes my use case

```
enum Types = {
  ADD = 'ADD',
  REMOVE = 'REMOVE',
};

/** I would like type-safety and autocompletion for the payload parameter */
const handleAdd = (state, payload) => ({...state, payload});

/** I would like to ensure that all types declared in Types are implemented */
export const reducers = new Map([
  [Types.ADD, handleAdd],
  [Types.REMOVE, handleRemove]
]);
```

Comment: `Map` isn't really typed in such a way to make this work for you.  You'd need to come up with your own custom typings `interface MyMap {...}` and `interface MyMapConstructor {...}` which may or may not be actual subtypes of `Map` and `MapConstructor`.  That's an awful lot of work for something that, when you're all done, gives you the same functionality as your `Values` type.  How much do you need this?

Comment: Edit: Added more code to the original post.

I prefer the above structure rather than objects because I am considering using Symbols as the keys, and because it looks more structured/strict.

Comment: The first example doesn't seem to be an error to me

Comment: Correct Juan, my first use-case is actually solved.

I have also thought of declaring these key, values as Arrays with strict type-checking and then have less strict type-checking on the Maps, but I am not sure yet if it will work.

Comment: Can't objects have `Symbol` keys too?  And with your `enum` example you can have `const reducers = {[Types.ADD]: handleAdd, [Types.REMOVE]: handleRemove}`.

Comment: Object mappings are from `string -> object` as far as I know. For the reducers, I would like the parameters of the functions to infer which type they will receive as the payload. My actions are FSA compliant with type and payload as properties.

Comment: Symbols can be object keys: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/symbols.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the closest I can imagine getting, although I still don't understand why we don't just use plain objects to begin with:

```
type ObjectToEntries<O extends object> = { [K in keyof O]: [K, O[K]] }[keyof O]

interface ObjectMap<O extends object> {
  forEach(callbackfn: <K extends keyof O>(
    value: O[K], key: K, map: ObjectMap<O>
  ) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
  get<K extends keyof O>(key: K): O[K];
  set<K extends keyof O>(key: K, value: O[K]): this;
  readonly size: number;
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<ObjectToEntries<O>>;
  entries(): IterableIterator<ObjectToEntries<O>>;
  keys(): IterableIterator<keyof O>;
  values(): IterableIterator<O[keyof O]>;
  readonly [Symbol.toStringTag]: string;
}

interface ObjectMapConstructor {
  new <E extends Array<[K, any]>, K extends keyof any>(
    entries: E
  ): ObjectMap<{ [P in E[0][0]]: Extract<E[number], [P, any]>[1] }>;
  new <T>(): ObjectMap<Partial<T>>;
  readonly prototype: ObjectMap<any>;
}

const ObjectMap = Map as ObjectMapConstructor;
```

The idea is to make a new interface, `ObjectMap`, which is specifically dependent on an object type `O` to determine its key/value relationship.  And then you can say that the `Map` constructor can act as an `ObjectMap` constructor.  I also removed any methods that can change which keys are actually present (and the `has()` method is redundantly `true` also).

I can go through the trouble of explaining each method and property definition, but it's a lot of type-juggling.  In short you want to use `K extends keyof O` and `O[K]` to represent the types normally represented by `K` and `V` in `Map<K, V>`.

The constructor is a bit more annoying in that type inference doesn't work the way you'd like, so guaranteeing type safety comes in two steps:

```
// let the compiler infer the type returned by the constructor
const myMapInferredType = new ObjectMap([
  ['key1', 'v'], 
  ['key2', 1],  
]);

// make sure it's assignable to `ObjectMap<Values>`: 
const myMap: ObjectMap<Values> = myMapInferredType;
```

If your `myMapInferredType` doesn't match `ObjectMap<Values>` (e.g., you are missing keys or have the wrong value types) then `myMap` will give you errors.

Now you can use `myMap` as an `ObjectMap<Values>`, similarly to how you'd use a `Map` instance, with `get()` and `set()`, and it should be type safe.

Please note again... this seems like a lot of work for a more complex object with trickier typings and no more functionality than a plain object.  I would seriously warn anyone using a `Map` whose keys are subtypes of `keyof any` (that is, `string | number | symbol`) to strongly [consider using a plain object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript) instead, and be sure that your use case really necessitates a `Map`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AFQPYFEB2wBOAlhAM4A8MUEAHsBDgCYlQaIrAB8UAvFAN5QA2gGkohHFADWEEBgBmsALoAuIcIA0sEYsVQAvoOmyFMRQFgAUJfF18cgIbJo8JKgCy9sBSq16TFmyoXHyWUGFQchj4WI4AFgAUyPYANslwjpJyOKpkojR0jMxG8rAc8aHhlQBuKQCuEKow2ppGqhpQALaejYHAHl4wHBVhAJQ8XFUYhAyawLGEJACC+ADmAPyq9jggI6qT0wDcw1ArEMC5PgX+xSZlrVDCu1rCikcWlSRnF-l+RTIlg3i93aNWS9Ua2iecwWb0q+Ag9gYGBwyRAUBIhAAXg0oDhah04BB8LDwoIAMogAkYZIAOkItnswCiiniTwAkgy4MkIByiYyohRephcARiORBhwSWF6KLSKzVLz8PYuTyGUz8ILXOhsHgiKQKBxJccjCR5VBFcruRb1WQbqUpVBQfVTezOVa1QKmnbTEb3uF4YjkaihBSqbSmWTRTgVmh7CsVOioys3npLNY8ESHE5YL1+gBhZEkAi1VBRfjHHAQADuUDIWEuvygyyVIDIIk0WxAig4mjyvkKUn+Ck7ZWOlRlepIqiwxyeLnY-TIAkEAAUxBIsIIAAyKbc6ae0JWoOuCPEEomKTSrjvbbuCACMuj0vsqlZrZDQZTnuc8ZBX9nwYBCBSD9DQdAMkRRNEwHwDAmVASAei1RcRxTNMLGQQtgBzZDPB4KB+igexmHndxPALHAi3wEt1TedCEOgAA1OpSHwkI-TCAByIx7041QqPEZNjm4mQACY+NxfFCWJSxUwsAB6eSoG5bC5mgTCOjAQhuXwdc5CJKA1MM8BoHhYBanwSsGCgOA0SMzDKOLUt8EsByi06EB+jZHB9PweEGDQEz8LfHCF08eJBGOQQRJAXjNE4qpOMvKKYvEzRH3USxFBGOiFKUrppHRCzoHpTjmGIjEVhwS1oCZKAAANSL6X9mLBUgOHq1RXKwjz+iQsKvFa50uF4DpPM8bzfP8wLIFyoA)

Comment: Thanks for taking giving of your time to explain this is such great detail. It works as it stands now, but I will have to consider if it is worth to use over a plain object, especially since I likely have to cast key as key.

Comment: Then I assume this would be a feasible option, especially because Map ensures order of insertion.

Comment: You care about order of insertion?  `ObjectMap<O>` doesn't know about the order of keys in `O` so it won't help you with that at compile time.  Not sure why you care about order exactly but I could imagine a type that does guarantee orders with tuple types instead of arrays... but this is even more complex and I think I need to run away screaming now. ‍♂️

Comment: Hahaha, well, now that I think of it, I may have startled you needlessly Insertion order isn't important as it is a map, so each key can only be represented once.

Comment: @jcalz Did anything change in TypeScript since then? I would also really love to be able to use Map, because I need to be able to sort properties.

Comment: @ŁukaszZaroda Nothing has changed that I know of.  I'm not sure what you mean by "sort" here. Depending on your use case it may be possible to write custom typings for it, but a comment section isn't a great place to explore that.  You might want to make your own question post for it.

Comment: @jcalz I meant that if order of keys matter for someone, he is kind of stuck with Map, because it actually handles that (basic js objects don't), and it's a shame that we are losing some typings when we convert our objects to Maps. No questions yet :) .