# Is it possible to infer the type of a generic index signature?

Tags: typescript

I wan't to create a generic function for validating objects.
I want it to accept an options object of the following signature:

```
export interface ValidationOptions<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
  validators: Map<K, (value: T[K]) => string | null>    
}
```

I want to be able to map from K to an array of validator functions that would accept an argument of type T[K]. The issue i have is that T[K] will resolve to each possible value in T, and not the specific value for the given key.

The code below should hopefully clarify what i mean.

```
export interface ValidationOptions<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> {
    validators: Map<K, (value: T[K]) => string | null>    
}

function fooValidator(value: string) {
    if (value === "foo") {
        return "Value can't be foo"
    }

    return null;
}

function isNotTrueValidator(value: boolean) {
    if (!value) {
        return "Value must be true"
    }

    return null;
}

interface ObjectToValidate {
    stringy: string;
    booly: boolean;
}


//(value: T[K]) => string | null will resolve to value: string | boolean here
//Can i make it resolve to the type for the given property instead? 
const options: ValidationOptions<ObjectToValidate> = {
    //This results in an error with strictFunctionTypes enabled
    validators: new Map([
        //How can i 
        ["stringy", fooValidator] 
    ])
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest giving up on using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if the intent is just to hold values for string-based keys.  That's what a plain old object is for.  Importantly for TypeScript, there is a lot of support for object-based types, and you can easily represent the behavior you expect from `validators` via a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), like this:

```
export interface ValidationOptions<T> {
    validators: { [K in keyof T]?: (value: T[K]) => string | null }
}

const options: ValidationOptions<ObjectToValidate> = {
    validators: {
        stringy: fooValidator
    }
}
```

If for some reason you need to keep using `Map`, the built-in [TypeScript typings](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.4.1/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) won't work, because they act more like a record type where each key is `K` and each value is `V` and the two types are independent.  One can represent a new type called, say, [`ObjectMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908008/2887218) whose typing is based on an underlying relationship between keys and values, but that's a lot of type munging to get where you're going.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I started of with an object based approach but ran into some issues with with using keyof T as an index signature, but it seems like i need to read up on mappped types. 

Again, thank you very much!