# How to define Map with correlation between a key type and a value type, while they both are unions

Tags: typescript

Here is the example which shows what I want to achieve. It almost works except 2 problems:

1. Set does not show an error on incorrect code
2. Immer Draft type (or any DeepWritable utility type) completely messes up this trick

Basically it seems to me that what I am doing here isn't really a thing. So the question is: is there some other way to do the same thing?

```
type Opaque<Type, Token = unknown> = Type & {
  readonly __opaque__: Token
}

type AnimalId = CatId | DogId

type Animal = Cat | Dog

type CatId = Opaque<number, Cat>

type Cat = {
  readonly kind: 'Cat'
  readonly id: CatId
}

type DogId = Opaque<number, Dog>

type Dog = {
  readonly kind: 'Dog'
  readonly id: DogId
}

const cat: Cat = {
    kind: 'Cat',
    id: 1 as CatId,
}

const dog: Dog = {
    kind: 'Dog',
    id: -1 as DogId,
}

const animals: Map<CatId, Cat> & Map<DogId, Dog> & Map<AnimalId, Animal> = new Map()

animals.set(cat.id, cat) // no error should be here

animals.set(cat.id, dog) // wanna see error here

const test1: Cat | undefined = animals.get(cat.id) // no error should be here

const test2: Dog | undefined = animals.get(dog.id) // no error should be here

const test4: Animal | undefined = animals.get(1 as AnimalId) // no error should be here

const test3 = animals.get(3) // wanna see error here
```

Comment: Why do you expect error here: `animals.set(cat.id, cat) // no error should be here`

Comment: @captain-yossarian it says "no error"

Comment: I bet 10$ that you should just make a wrapper function with appropriate overloadings.

Comment: Looks like you owe $10 to jcalz now

Comment: @gyzerok yes) this guy is phenomenal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intersection `Map<CatId, Cat> & Map<DogId, Dog>` should *conceptually* be enough to give you the behavior you want, but in practice this does not work.  Intersections of function types produce [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), and overloaded call signatures in TypeScript are resolved *separately*.  They are not combined to allow a single call to invoke both call signatures (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107)).  So with just `Map<CatId, Cat> & Map<DogId, Dog>`, you cannot call `animals.get(1 as AnimalId)`; an `AnimalId` is neither a `CatId` nor a `DogId`, as required by each of the two separate call signatures.

---

In order to address this, you have apparently added in the "missing" `Map<AnimalId, Animal>`.  Unfortunately this goes too far.  You not only get the desirable `get()` behavior, you get the *undesirable* `set()` behavior.  Since `cat.id` is an `AnimalId`, and `dog` is an `Animal`, a `Map<AnimalId, Animal>` would certainly allow you to call `animals.set(cat.id, dog)`. I won't go into the pedantic details of covariance and contravariance, but generally speaking, if reading accepts unions-of-things, then *writing* should accept *intersections*-of-things, not unions.  So the only methods of `Map<AnimalId, Animal>` you'd *like* to support are ones involving *reading* the contents.

Fortunately for us, there is a [`ReadonlyMap` interface defined in the TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d7d8f33def2affef86ce1d0f9fb604523ef515ca/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L38-L43) which serves just this purpose.  So I'd be inclined to annotate `animals` like this:

```
const animals: Map<CatId, Cat> & Map<DogId, Dog>
  & ReadonlyMap<AnimalId, Animal> = new Map();
```

Once you do that, you get the behavior you're looking for, at least for your example code:

```
animals.set(cat.id, cat) // okay
animals.set(cat.id, dog) // error, no overload matches this call
const test1: Cat | undefined = animals.get(cat.id) // okay
const test2: Dog | undefined = animals.get(dog.id) // okay
const test4: Animal | undefined = animals.get(1 as AnimalId) // okay
const test3 = animals.get(3) // error, number is not AnimalId
```

There may, of course, be other use cases that this definition does not support.  Overloads do have some weird quirks.  If you really truly care, you might need to handwrite your own interface that behaves exactly how you expect a multi-type `Map` to act.  This is an interesting exercise I've done before for a different case (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907009/typescript-how-can-i-make-entries-in-an-es6-map-based-on-a-union-type)) and honestly it's not that terrible.  But I won't go into that here, especially if the above simpler intersection works for your use cases.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mCGBHArhAPAFXBANFDA9gNYQB2UAvFMqUaQQO6kB8l+2UAZFAN4BQUKACcI8ACYFSAGxBQA+nIIIUEBQC58xMnwC+fPqEhQAgqQCWAW3hSAkmLYBheMDtQAPlAAiBAOZ39htCmltaOzu5evgEcTi72VHBIqGikyBYARhBCeLHM0UaxbPyCIuKSMlBEZqRiGgDksXUCwqIS0rJmtVCx-noGHN5+8bDKyakZWXiDef1Gg0XNpW0VVTX1g00lreUdXYO9+gDGkgDOwFCHzhqFVMWV1V0NznU4zZ0aAIxQ8CfdznavPrHUhnKASHwaea3ZqrR4bV6Cd5QAC0Xx+kSGgKOp3O8HMVikJw0AFl4GA0D0xDlnKxuKTyfsqRi8oJuAAlbbteloYIEgEmfHWVhUUgQBhQekACgAlABufR8PEhQkAOhOEGAksuwBVnTw2ulUAA9EaoMR4CBFYLVerNdrdUzwYaTVAskICNkoPQzQA3LJSAjiKBWYCHAAWEF+wDDZl+lykUj4wNBwEjwA+13CHhoYggADNqhBhkqCScVT4NVrnA7nabzZbk+dU2cAEyQ3wRHP5wvF61liua8E1411ogWpM4qDN4AAFg0vNC2Zq3dFveV-craN+C9sYlrZrHDcn04AzGwS9YN5qT-u3R68ONMkIoLGvQRzju7EA)

Comment: Amazing response! I love how detailed it is an how perfectly the result works.

There is second part to my problem though. Can you check if you are able to solve that one also?

Unfortunately Draft<T> modificator from Immer messes up what this type is trying to achieve. It will make animals.get to behave as it was just Map<AnimalId, Animal>.

Here is the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-kare-7wb3v?file=/src/immer-bug.ts

I wonder if there is a way to modify Draft<T> type to make it workZ

Comment: Did not know that there is ReadonlyMap )

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if you can modify `Draft` in such a way as to allow it to transform an intersection-of-maps into something reasonable.  There's no simple programmatic way to tease apart an intersection into its constituents.  You're likely going to need to hand-convert `ReadonlyMap<A, B> & ReadonlyMap<C, D> & ReadonlyMap<A|C, B|D>` to `Map<A, B> & Map<C, D> & ReadonlyMap<A|C, B|D>` to get the behavior you want, without trying to pass it through a general-purpose transformer like `Draft`.  Maybe someone else could figure out how but I'd expect it to be fragile even if so.

Comment: @jcalz yeah this sounds about right. I was able to handcraft the types and extend the Draft type so it is aware of them. In the end a bit of a type churn, but worth it in my opinion.

However trying to apply it to my codebase I actually got stuck with the last problem. In practice I would like to allow animals.set(animal.id, animal) which gets prohibited because of ReadonlyMap usage. The thing is - you can't construct animal so that it's id does not match it's type. But compiler doesn't get it.

Is there something more that could be done here?

Comment: In other words:

const animal = cat as Animal; animals.set(animal.id, animal) // no error should be here

Comment: I've made a codesandbox with updated code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/type-tricks-7wb3v?file=/src/tricky-types.ts