# Typescript Map<enum, set<enum>> "No overload matches this call", but I don't get why?

Tags: typescript, dictionary, enums

I am creating a boardgame in Typescript. In it I declare the following:

```
export enum PieceType {
    PAWN,
    KNIGHT2,
    KNIGHT4,
    WIZARD,
    KING
}

export class Board {
    // ...
    private takeRules: Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>> = new Map([
        [PieceType.PAWN, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD])],
        [PieceType.KNIGHT2, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD, PieceType.KING])],
        [PieceType.KNIGHT4, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD, PieceType.KING])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])]
    ]);
    private enchantRules: Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>> = new Map([
        [PieceType.WIZARD, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([PieceType.WIZARD])]
    ]);
    // ...
}
```

This errors as follows:

```
[tsl] ERROR in ./src/board.ts(28,60)
      TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(iterable: Iterable<readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>]>): Map<PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<...>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '([PieceType.WIZARD, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>] | [PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.WIZARD>])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>]>'.
      The types returned by '[Symbol.iterator]().next(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'IteratorResult<[PieceType.WIZARD, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>] | [PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.WIZARD>], any>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>], any>'.
          Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[PieceType.WIZARD, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>] | [PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.WIZARD>]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>], any>'.
            Type 'IteratorYieldResult<[PieceType.WIZARD, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>] | [PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.WIZARD>]>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorYieldResult<readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>]>'.
              Type '[PieceType.WIZARD, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>] | [PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.WIZARD>]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>]'.
                Type '[PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.WIZARD>]' is not assignable to type 'readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>]'.
                  Types of property '1' are incompatible.
                    Type 'Set<PieceType.WIZARD>' is not assignable to type 'Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>'.
                      Type 'PieceType.WIZARD' is not assignable to type 'PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>])[]): Map<PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.KING, Set<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type 'Set<PieceType.WIZARD>' is not assignable to type 'Set<PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4>'.
```

If I put the second map in comments: no problem.
If I ommit the wizard enum in the last line of the second map: no problem. I can even put the ommitted value in using the constructor without a problem.
E.g.

```
    private takeRules: Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>> = new Map([
        [PieceType.PAWN, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD])],
        [PieceType.KNIGHT2, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD, PieceType.KING])],
        [PieceType.KNIGHT4, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD, PieceType.KING])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])]
    ]);
    private enchantRules: Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>> = new Map([
        [PieceType.WIZARD, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([])]
    ]);

   // ...

    constructor() {
        // ...
        this.enchantRules.get(PieceType.KING).add(PieceType.WIZARD)
    }
```

I really don't understand how this is possible?

Comment: It is not clear wich is line 28 (ie wich line produces the error)

Comment: Line 28 is `private enchantRules: Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>> = new Map([`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very interesting question.
Here is solution:

```js
export enum PieceType {
    PAWN,
    KNIGHT2,
    KNIGHT4,
    WIZARD,
    KING
}

export class Board {
    // ...
    private takeRules = new Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>>([
        [PieceType.PAWN, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD])],
        [PieceType.KNIGHT2, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD, PieceType.KING])],
        [PieceType.KNIGHT4, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4, PieceType.WIZARD, PieceType.KING])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])]
    ]);
    private enchantRules = new Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>>([
        [PieceType.WIZARD, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([PieceType.WIZARD])]
    ])
}
```

I just defined generics for `Map` instead of defining whole type : `new Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>>`.

But main question, why the error occured?

Let's make some analyze of :

```js
   private enchantRules: Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>> = new Map([
        [PieceType.WIZARD, new Set([PieceType.PAWN, PieceType.KNIGHT2, PieceType.KNIGHT4])],
        [PieceType.KING, new Set([PieceType.WIZARD])]
    ]);
```

If you put type definition `Map<PieceType, Set<PieceType>>` before `equal` sign, TS will try to infer these type. Hence, if you put some `PieceType` enum value, which don't exists in previous entity, it will throw an error.

Take a look on simplier example:

```js
type Fst = PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4
type Scd = PieceType.WIZARD

let fst: Fst = PieceType.PAWN;
let scd: Scd = PieceType.WIZARD;

scd = fst; // error
```

You can't assign `fst` to `scd`, but, if you add `PAWN` enum type to `Scd` type, it will work:

```js
type Fst = PieceType.PAWN | PieceType.KNIGHT2 | PieceType.KNIGHT4
type Scd = PieceType.WIZARD | PieceType.PAWN

let fst: Fst = PieceType.PAWN;
let scd: Scd = PieceType.WIZARD;

scd = fst; // ok
```

Let's go back to our problem. Because `WIZARD` was not defined in first Map value `V`, you are unable to use WIZARD at all.

SO, I believe you should stick with explicit generic type definition instead of defininf your type directly near variable definition.

P.S. You may find this [answer also interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891135/how-to-define-map-with-correlation-between-a-key-type-and-a-value-type-while-th)

I'm open to criticizm, so feel free to point my mistakes.
Thanks