# Generic data by object key

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

This is the code I have:

```
type Bucket = {
  [key:string]:Map<string,{data:any}>
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to create a `type` that would allow me to have `custom` data by key. As you can see in the below code, I would like to strongly type the `data` object for every key. I've tried by having the generic object on the `Bucket` type but that locks all the keys to the same data.

Is there a way to have different strongly typed `data` for every key?

```
const bucket:Bucket = {
  a:new Map(),
  b:new Map<string,{data:boolean}>()
}

bucket.a.set('a',{data:1})
bucket.b.set('b',{data:'b'}) // this should error

const getA = bucket.a.get('a') // data is any - should be inferred to number?
const getB = bucket.b.get('b') // data is any - should be boolean
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=66#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgYwNYWFAvFA3gWAFBRQDaKIAXAM7ABOAlgHYDmAumQLICGYAPFXUwBosAEw7AOZDvRABfAHz4Z+ZXgQB7elSgAjRCmBl4yVBmz5CE+hADuUTmAAUASgHmdZK7fu8aDRkNFxMm01NQAbCCl5Z0UVXWNgADoORIpUBwByDgyAsQkARhknfHj9RO1U9IztHJE8smqMoqgAehaoYAALWgooCk61ODDhKAhqajVqFXVNNEZUAEFTUtRkxPngTOynVvbAjigeqCkQKABaPoGhke1oBgAzMeoIEeA1KHo4AFtb6gB+fAzLQbGDLPSrCobTI1HZtKD7Q69E7nS6DYY6aAhcKRehAA)

Comment: With identity function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgYwNYWFAvFA3gWAFBRQDaKIAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmAuhQLICGYAPNfcwA02KABNOwThU4MQUAL4A+fPPz4EAewbUoCGhAnRMPACpQIAD2AQGoyrEQpgigBQAjR6gomAlBkVQHsioANxqeJraaEFOGLr6hi64BFBSUAwQAO5QXLz8jEzCWGISaQxwALZuEDQKrj6C+IRuFBnZuXy0BUUlkhRuGhoANgYMdS4+KpN4+DGoAHSc85SoLgDknGs94n1QAIwK03PA827Lq2tuWyI7aZdrh1AA9E9QwAAWdPaU7xpwQ6JzDQaBoaOFIjomKgAIJxY6LeZQ4DrTZ+F69ThQL6pWRQAC0VF+-0B1SxDAAZjV9IDgBp0pVqjQAPzqLSQ1AwOGeE5nJHrK5o163LH2GRyAk-P4AwLQAbDUZAA You'll still need to type `a` explicitly

Comment: I bet 10$ that one of these links might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891135/how-to-define-map-with-correlation-between-a-key-type-and-a-value-type-while-th     and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978153/typescript-mapenum-setenum-no-overload-matches-this-call-but-i-dont-get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define a `Bucket` type with an indexed signature (`{ [x: <key type>] : <value type> }`), you tell the compiler that there is no direct correlation between specific elements and their types. Also, `any` is not a "placeholder" type, it [opts out](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) of type checking. The compiler thus shows you what you told it, that:

1. all keys of `bucket` are of type `string`
2. `bucket` has values of type `Map<string, { data: any }`.

You then assign an object to the `bucket` variable. At this point, the value is checked for *compatibility* with the provided type (`Bucket`) and since you disabled type checking for `data` member, `any`thing goes, thus no error.

Next, when you `get` value of a member of `bucket`, the type is inferred as `{ data: any; } | undefined` because there is no guarantee that `"a"` or `"b"` will be present in `[x: string]`, hence the value can be `undefined`. We already talked about why `data` is not narrowed.

If you remove type annotation from the `bucket`, you will notice the inference improves drastically because the type is now inferred as well: `{ a: Map<any, any>; b: Map<string, { data: boolean; }>`. At the same time, you lose type checking for what members of `bucket` can contain.

So, what can you do about it? You need to explicitly tell the compiler what is the correlation between certain keys and values. Making your `Bucket` generic can help us achieve just that:

```ts
type Bucket<T> = {
  [ P in keyof T ]: Map<string, { data: T[P] }>
}
```

Now you have correctly inferred `data` types, assurance about the shape of `bucket`, and autocompletion at a cost of being more verbose which is a small price to pay for these benefits (besides, you can make the type parameter an interface or a type):

```ts
type Bucket<T> = {
  [ P in keyof T ]: Map<string, { data: T[P] }>
}

const bucket: Bucket<{ a: number, b: boolean, c?: string }> = {
  a:new Map(),
  b:new Map(),
};

bucket.a.set('a', { data: 1 })
bucket.b.set('b', { data: 'b' }) // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

const getA = bucket.a.get('a') // data is number
const getB = bucket.b.get('b') // data is boolean
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgYwNYWAHgCoD4oF4oDeAsAFBRQDaUAClAJYB2UKIA9gGZQZQC6AXFACyAQzBoAzsABOjAOYAaQlAAmw4MIEYK1HlAC+WUntKkErBpKgAjRCmAD4yVGgJQNUBnAC2ViFMVWAlasrAA2EMIMiggA-AKSMgyy+jj4xGRufAwQAO5CogAUAJTypOSB2XkiYMWlJHoA3CYkNk7AAHTC7eKoBQDkwn2KrqrqAgCM+kWkrXbtVt29fVZDSqPuy31TUAD0O1zg0H0Jclt04h6swG7i4nSyDMJW4VDArK+HUMsh4ZF9zWYLNdZKgAIJ4ay2VCddog4D9QZFXb7db0C6eHx+UzmSxwmAQ2bQhZw-orJF7FRqYRo6w-CIMIA)

---

An identity function like the one mentioned by [Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136259/generic-data-by-object-key#comment116927292_66136259) does the same thing - removes explicit type annotation from `bucket` while preserving type-checking (`extends Bucket` constraint) and returning a literal type (`<T>(a:T) => T` form). It has a cost of emitting a function in compiled code, but it allows you to infer the `bucket` type.

Comment: @IvanV. NP - mapped types with generic type parameters is the first thing that comes to mind when I need to correlate keys and values (although I do like the idea of using an identity function as well)