# How to use `(K | V)[][]` as `ReadonlyArray<[K, V]>` in a Map?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary

I would like to use a `(K | V)[][]` as `ReadonlyArray<[K, V]>` in a Map constructor. Lets say that our V is an interface `IItem` and K a basic `number`.

```
interface IItem {
    key: number;
    val: string;
}

const items = [[1, {key: 1, val: "a"}]] 
const ze_map = new Map<number, IItem>(items);
console.log(JSON.stringify([...ze_map]));
```

By default, typescript will perceive the type of items as `: (number | IItem)[][]`. This will not work and throw an error:

> Argument of type '(number | { key: number; val: string; })[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[{}, {}]>'.
> Type '(number | { key: number; val: string; })[]' is missing the following properties from type '[{}, {}]': 0, 1

Luckily for us we can force the type to `Array<[number, IItem]>` to please `Map`.

```
const items2 : Array<[number, IItem]> = [[1, {key: 1, val: "a"}]] 
const ze_map2 = new Map<number, IItem>(items2);
console.log(JSON.stringify([...ze_map]));
```

This work as expected. Alright, lets move to my problem. What if we cannot force the type?

```
const arr = [
    { key: 3, val: 'bar' },
    { key: 5, val: 'world' }
];
const result: Array<[number, IItem]> = arr.map(i => ([i.key, i]));

const ze_map3 = new Map(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify([...ze_map]));
```

This will not work because here `(number | { key: number; val: string; })[][]` is not `Array<[number, IItem]>`. So, how to use `(K | V)[][]` as `ReadonlyArray<[K, V]>` in a Map?

You can try all the code [online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKsgW2QbwFDKHIDWEAngFzIgCumARtANwFEBucANlQM5hSgA5iwC+ePAgD2IPsmBYeyKgApaDaMgA+aDBEwBKANoBdE4QC8yQ4YCMAGlylKye8g7dkAIjieRx48gS0rIAXhAA+phwAA7IliAQAO7IALIxADxqjFAO6FgAfMryejz6LFIykpwQAHSckoLKAFIAygDyAHI1fAIggsAwZMqGNaNhkTHG+mXiQTJgcgoATErIAIJQUHBk6YZZ0Lm6mMb5cVa2DjhOVK7uVN6+-oEVoRFR0SvxSakZ+zk6BSKyxmLyqtXqjVanW6-CEAyGIzGb0m0xYc1kcE2Z0MrEIOBI5CoAGYHHdkAByeiY8nIER2XG4AnOACspK4VHJiUkUE4ABMaWJjOVggsoBAeDROAtLJioDV3kU4qdhsAak4HMApjMAPTa9ZQQR0CDgZCSGDIMBkaIocmqOjZLSM67Ue3MNzs5A9IRMWlGUzGGnARQgSQLOA8HjAQQgOD0aoWyTIaKYuCYCCQKCm82W60UgBKEDgvOknDIGy2O0MODpuD8+XJNTwusIABUrTa7epM9p8c6-j6yV6+j6RH7A4pMEHI30LQALFAwKr1RJCJNQSTWqBgYDi5AwdfYHM2qs16sBqgABgcNnRC3G7yJZwSyTS0WUYolUpBwTBdQazXaLoh36QZhlGGp7xRGYgA)

I read both [How to define Map with correlation between a key type and a value type, while they both are unions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891135/how-to-define-map-with-correlation-between-a-key-type-and-a-value-type-while-th) and [Typescript Map<enum, set<enum>> "No overload matches this call", but I don't get why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65978153/typescript-mapenum-setenum-no-overload-matches-this-call-but-i-dont-get) without finding the solution. I may missed the solution.

I also read the [MDN entry on Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) which say that it should work as expected and if you try in vanilla JS it does work as expected:

```javascript
var arr = [
    { key: 3, val: 'bar' },
    { key: 5, val: 'world' }
];

var result = arr.map(i => [i.key, i]);
const ze_map = new Map(result);

console.log(JSON.stringify([...ze_map]));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoIwFEX3fsXboAl2MS4Q/AATdXAkxFSopFpb8lohaPz2@pSYeNdzz7nIQfoGdR8W1rUqxkEiSEQooWJAe8JVTTksMxikySE5SUzglf2z1Y@NDk1LlNUFY58QKn83gVpUFDfZpxrKNVRakJeBrnnBGmd9gIc6EqajVSNs6TibxL8HZ5Qwrks3h/1O@IDadvo8pZUQYjZrzguI8Q0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the body of the `.map` callback.  Whenever a function returns an array, Typescript will interpret the return type as a normal array type rather than a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).

#### Avoid `as`

The `as` assertion will work, but it can be dangerous because it tells Typescript "consider this type as `[number, IItem]` even if it really isn't" rather than telling Typescript "I expect this type to be `[number, IItem]` so please make sure that it is."  In your situation the `as` is not required because it really is type `[number, IItem]`.  We just need to get typescript to interpret it that way.

#### Set a Generic

The easiest way to do this is by setting the generic type parameter on the `.map` function.  The generic variable here sets the return type of the callback, so we set it to `[number, IItem]`.

```
const result = arr.map<[number, IItem]>(i => [i.key, i]); // result has type [number, IItem][]

const ze_map = new Map(result); // no errors :)
```

#### Externalize the Callback

Another approach is to define your map callback `i => [i.key, i]` as its own function so that you can annotate the return type.

```
const toTuple = (i: IItem): [number, IItem] => [i.key, i];

const result = arr.map(toTuple); // result has type [number, IItem][]

const ze_map = new Map(result); // no errors :)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3YQw)

Answer (score 1):

I feel that there may be a better way to achieve this but you can force the type by casting in the `map` routine:

```
const arr = [
    { key: 3, val: 'bar' },
    { key: 5, val: 'world' }
];
const result = arr.map(i => ([i.key, i] as [number, IItem])); // here come the trick
const ze_map3 = new Map(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify([...ze_map3]));
```

The `as` keyword is a Type Assertion which tells tsc to consider the object as another type (i.e. our `[K, V]`) than the type the compiler infers the object to be (i.e. `(K | V)[]`).

The good news is that the `as [K, V]` is totally transparent in the js output:

```
"use strict";
const arr = [
    { key: 3, val: 'bar' },
    { key: 5, val: 'world' }
];
const result = arr.map(i => [i.key, i]);
const ze_map3 = new Map(result);
console.log(JSON.stringify([...ze_map3]));
```

[Try it Online](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKsgW2QbwFDKHIDWEAngFzIgCumARtANwFEBucANlQM5hSgA5iwC+ePAgD2IPsjhQoyALzIA2q0I4S5KgGYANMg7dkAcnrzTyEfo25tlZAFZDxqqYDukqJwAmVsQBdFglpWSgIHhpOMGU5BQA6TDgABwAKYGUAPmQ01WAE0jJDYEC5HjVaBmhDdCxAgEoGlikZWIAvCAB9ZJTdOJAID2QAWVS0iKiY5tCZSU4IBM5JQTSAKQBlAHkAOQS+ARBBYBgyPISLzp7U3UaZoA)

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55781571/1248177)