# derived generic class cannot be assigned to base generic class in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a map storing all kinds of element. Defined as follow:

```js
const map = new Map<string, IComponent<IBase>>();
```

I want to use this map to store instance of `IComponent<IBase>`, `IComponent<INumber>`, `IComponent<IText>` and so on.

The base interface is defined as follow:

```js
// base interface
interface IBase {}
// base component type
export type IComponent<T extends IBase> = React.FC<T>;
```

Now I want to add a `NumberComponent`

```js
// derived interface
interface INumber extends IBase {
    someNumber: number;
}
// some component
const NumberComponent: IComponent<INumber> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>{props.someNumber}</div>
    );
}
```

I use `map.set('number', NumberComponent)` to store it to the map, but I got

```
Argument of type 'FC<INumber>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FC<IBase>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type 'PropsWithChildren<IBase>' is not assignable to type 'PropsWithChildren<INumber>'.
      Property 'someNumber' is missing in type 'PropsWithChildren<IBase>' but required in type 'INumber'.
```

I know I could use `map.set('number', NumberComponent as IComponent<IBase>)` to cast the type. However, I don't want to use `as`. Is there another way to solve this?

[demo on ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirgCMUBnJOYAOxiSk3SXPc7decAJIAhJiwDeAX2q00uSGyQc4MAJ5g+SAB6RY6rSxEBhJRBUcAPABU4ezmwAmjUROYA+OAF5ExGAA6ADFTO08KSho4Zy5gADckZ1YOLh40PgE04REAOQBXEDouB10nV3dJOClyODq4RlwkAqKuAC44NkLiqAo5aMaQFkVwS1UYckU2RngWnvNRqxgOswsl6zzurm8-AAowHDBGAEpfbxr6uCIYfKg2OF3ay-rrZwTPKQOII8DB5q2oDJrFQ3vFPE86sc+pRKFMZnAQCgwL5OkgAO5wACySOsMyg7AA5gAaUQLZTjDYeJCeTy7KHkRFgX5IGC7fBdVpQfAkuZcMljDj0xnM1nsgHcuC8qD8pZwJiktYU8SSTz08hAA)

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible what you're trying to achieve with the Map. I imagine you essentially want to be able to call `map.get('number');` and receive a typed Number component, however since only the value is typed, TypeScript won't know that there's the NumberComponent behind the key 'number'.

Comment: /play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocgeirgCMUBnJOYAOxiSk3SXPc7decAJIAhJiwDeAX2q00uSGyQc4MAJ5g+SAB6RY6rSxEBhJRBUcAPABU4ezmwAmjUROZwAvHFkA+b0RiGAA6ADFTOz8KSho4Zy5gADckZ1YOLh40PgFM4REAOQBXEDouB10nV3dJX3I4BrhGXCRi0q4ALjg2ErKoCjl+DKFs0VtHCqq3cVqpesbOSq7GGCh2AHMB+SaWuEVwS1UYckU2Fbg2vvMDqxguswtb60LergCfAAowHDBGAEpvAE5o04EQYEUoGw4B95iCGtZnMk-FJvhBfiFmiBWq8oDJrFREUk-LC4H8tidLOdxpVrsojvdaYcbCJqTB3tDUb8AV4gSSwRCoTC4Y0EUiUT9GCFFjA8QSkSS-uRBqdziAUGBAsDGgAiHrtKDarqXLiM24AGhJ2ulhrgrNNRwtMjgTD2lJgMQpZ3gCAgEBg9o4XWQ6FCEUCH25vJBKvgAfgPjVYCljhiIP5kLg1jj6kcXm1AAkkAAbIsQOAAdWgRec2rgVGiSqAA

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do. You just need to overload your `Map`

```js
import React from 'react'

interface IBase { }

export type IComponent<T extends IBase> = React.FC<T>;

interface INumber extends IBase {
  someNumber: number;
}


type MapOverloads = Map<string, IComponent<IBase>> & Map<string, IComponent<INumber>>
const map:MapOverloads  = new Map<string, IComponent<IBase>>();


const NumberComponent: IComponent<INumber> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>{props.someNumber}</div>
  );
}

const BaseComponent: IComponent<IBase> = (props) => {
  return null
}

map.set('number', NumberComponent)

map.set('base', BaseComponent)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQCEUBnRgbzgF9ykAD0iw4MAJ5hGTAMK5IlJNQA8AFThCalACbtmbTgD44AXkTEYAOgBiMtYYDc5KjToNmAOQCuIAEa0NQS1dfQ5uUjg4dlwkbz9aAC44Sh9-KCd%20cgkpOABZFDAAeQA3WgAbCBQQs3ywZXYYKCoAcwAaZjlwCEUVVjDDYwAyPIL6xpb22XlupRhlJji0gdI0boa4EAKE2pLyypDTZKQAdxG6hqbKNo7pnrm%20o0MACgBKJ3JVynXF2k6FWaSUy6d3mPygxjMTzAODA7BepmMXAicCIMC8UEocCeyMiym0wGKhi40IgsMs0RAsVStF4ygA9PjCci3qRMp91gYkH8ZtRAdyQQ8kBCsSTYfCTIjkaj0ZiUmUyqzyJswOSkDAnvgUvEoPh2mD%20bMXkqCqr1fhfGFdXBOQbqC8gA)

Main idea was shamelesly stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891135/how-to-define-map-with-correlation-between-a-key-type-and-a-value-type-while-th) of @jcalz

However, because `map` is mutable, and I assume you want it to be mutable, there is a problem with `getter`.

```js
const expectNumber = map.get('number') // IComponent<IBase> | undefined
```

P.S. You was not able to assign `IComponent<INumber>` to `IComponent<IBase>` because of contravariance

Comment: Thank you for your idea. This solution works, but it is not easy to scale. Now I only have `NumberComponent`, but in the future I'll have `DateComponent`, `TextComponent` and many many other components. And the definition for `MapOverLoads` will be longer and longer.

Comment: Do you want map to be mutable or not?

Comment: Sorry, I have not much time, but you can try to refactor your types according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65891135/how-to-define-map-with-correlation-between-a-key-type-and-a-value-type-while-th example

Comment: I am a little confusing why mutable or immutable matters.In my case, I want this map immutable. I use `map` instead of `object` because I want it to be used in many files. For example, I use `map.set('number', NumberComponent)` in `NumberComponent.tsx`. Others use `map.set('text', TextComponent)` in `TextComponent.tsx`. I try to avoid `object` because I want to scatter the registration.

Comment: If you want it to be immutable, you can\t use `set`