# Typescript Map. Value type inference based on key in class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I would like to declare a map member variable in class. What I currently have is the following:

(This compiles)

```
this.map = new Map <keyof T, T[keyof T]> ()
```

But I would like to constraint the values in the map to specific type based on the key type.
Ultimately what I need is the value type to be T[K]

Class parameterized type should include only the T.

Is this actually even possible?

Comment: Given `Map` is typed as `Map<T, K>` - it's impossible.

Comment: Just like in the other question, I wonder why this we want this instead of just a value of type `T` or `Partial<T>`, but ‍♂️

Comment: Im not sure how Partial<T> would solve the problem.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to store a value `map` of this special `Map` type as opposed to a value `x` of type `T` or `Partial<T>`?  What, specifically, are you doing with a `Map` that wouldn't be easier or more natural with the object?  `map.get("a")` looks like `x.a`; `map.set("a", 123)` looks like `x.a = 123`; `map.has("a")` looks like `"a" in x`;  You can iterate over object props with `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()` or `Object.values()`.  I'm not saying you don't have a good use case; i just have a hard time envisioning one.

Comment: In any case, the [answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908008/2887218) has an `ObjectMap<T>` type that should work the way you want.

Comment: @jcalz Used case would be getting correct value type based on the key. for example,  map.get("numberKey") would give value of type number

Comment: And how is that better than just reading the `numberKey` property on a value of type `T`?  That’s what objects are for: reading and writing properties whose keys are strings.  What advantage does a map give you over a plain object type?  Right now I can’t tell if you’ve considered using a plain object but dismissed it for a reason you haven’t said, or if you just haven’t considered it or understood the suggestion.