# How to infer the types of a Map's values using keyof

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Apologies if this has been asked already, I wasn't quite sure how to search for it.

Given a pre-defined type that maps keys to a type of value, is it possible to create a typed Map where the second parameter to the generic is inferred from the value used for the first?

For instance, I can do this with an object:

```
interface EntitiesMap {
    persons: Person
    pets: Pet
}

type EntitiesObject = { [K in keyof EntitiesMap]?: Array<EntitiesMap[k]> }

const a: EntitiesObject {
  persons: [person1, person2]
}

const b: EntitiesObject {
  persons: [person1, person2],
  pets: [pet1]
}
```

But I can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to do something similar with a Map:

```
// doesn't work
type EntitiesMap = Map<K in keyof EntitiesMap, Array<EntitiesMap[k]>>
```

Here's a more full example (and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAnsg3gKGSOWwAcIAuZAZzClAHN8BfffUSWRFABWmoD2IZBAAekEABNqaDNjyFipABZCIAOQCuAWwBG0KiB36oLNh2jwkyPmBHiIUmejCYcBYsngA3AfUgAYgICklS09CBMrOzgltyyrq4Q1ACycKQKnuRQgiBUfDlCikTkYPkQYGb4CAA2cNQyABICmtQQqjWSmcSgynC6mHDg1ADyugBWEAhleMgA2gDSyKDIANYQWAIwCZjAyWmkALoA-FQuu-vpi4dzh8jMyAC8eKyeAPQAVMgAwkPIAJLISQCEjKYAyADumGUyDgyAOAAoAJTIY7ID5vYrLEB9AZgIZgVLpKgHAA860223OSSJpAANDsaQdrgA+J7IEAQCHw9LIrFvN7Y3GDYYHEnpUlLMQSaRrDZbRl7WkM6lK5kLQ5s56c7mIpH8wW9foiwlinmkSXYuWUxWXem22ms9k6818rEMCr-HHG-HDAJQATaMbjUkAFXsMpkFIVqrtLIRZEoyFDKI8nmIUAqmigwjAYOoADojXiCaMJlMwHNE4csa9iB6wF7hb7Cf7A2Tw9LHLLo1S5Gr0vHE1QU9108hM2Bs7n80XvSXRekCw2E1hyPrPKxogghLRkKpWihtVzkM1Dx1JG6dyA9+QBKQahA20GJuyD21l575ybqM-gwiAHJslyAD9WvW8Kl-AMX3GN8Wg-Bsmx9Us-wmQDSlAthwLsO8HyfaCDjgw9P0bb8Wyg9teSA-ghEw7DkFKCjtEI553wgEikIXVsCKojCkSAA) it is in a TS playground)

```
interface Entity {
    type: string
}

interface Person extends Entity {
    phoneNumber: number
}

interface Pet extends Entity {
    favoriteFood: string
}

interface EntitiesMap {
    person: Person
    pet: Pet
}

class Household {
    inhabitantsObject: { [K in keyof EntitiesMap]?: EntitiesMap[K][] } = {}
    /* Can I do this with a Map() ? */
    inhabitantsMap: Map<keyof EntitiesMap, EntitiesMap[K]> = new Map()
    // inhabitantsMap: Map<K extends keyof EntitiesMap, EntitiesMap[K]> = new Map()
    // inhabitantsMap: Map<K in keyof EntitiesMap, EntitiesMap[K]> = new Map()

    getInhabitantsFromObj<T extends keyof EntitiesMap>(type: T) {
        return this.inhabitantsObject[type]
    }
    getInhabitantsFromMap<T extends keyof EntitiesMap>(type: T) {
        return this.inhabitantsMap.get(type)
    }
}

const house = new Household()

const peopleFromObj = house.getInhabitantsFromObj('person')
const petsFromObj = house.getInhabitantsFromObj('pet')

// these two values are 'any', but i'm guessing that is because
// inhabitantsMap does not have a valid type
const peopleFromMap = house.getInhabitantsFromMap('person')
const petsFromMap = house.getInhabitantsFromMap('pet')
```

Comment: `Map` doesn't work that way, it can't associate a specific key with a specific value, it simply takes a set of keys, and a set of values.

Comment: The closest you can get is `Map<keyof EntitiesMap, EntitiesMap[keyof EntitiesMap]>`, but unlike the object-based interface, `house.getInhabitantsFromMap('person')` and `house.getInhabitantsFromMap('pet')` both return the types `Person | Pet | undefined` instead of `Person | undefined` and `Pet | undefined` respectively.

Comment: In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54908008/2887218) to the linked question I show one approach how to give typings to `Map` so you can use them to hold the key/value pairings of an arbitrary object type (and I call it `ObjectMap` to give it a new name and not try to overload the default `Map` typings).  If I use that code here I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3aBAw), which behaves how you want.  But also in that answer I wonder if it's worth it, since a plain object has this functionality and is a lot simpler to use.  Anyway, hope that helps!