# Typescript event listener - type to props mapping

Tags: typescript, types

```
export enum GameEventType {
  EVENT_ONE = 'event-one',
  EVENT_TWO = 'event-two',
  EVENT_THREE = 'event-three'
}

export type GameEvent =
  | { type: GameEventType.EVENT_ONE; parameter: string }
  | { type: GameEventType.EVENT_TWO; anotherParam: SomeType }
  | { type: GameEventType.EVENT_THREE; };

type GameEventListener = (event: GameEvent) => void;

export class GameObserver {
  private listenerMap = new Map<GameEventType, GameEventListener[]>();

  public on(eventType: GameEventType, listener: GameEventListener) {
    const existing = this.listenerMap.get(eventType) ?? [];
    existing.push(listener);
    this.listenerMap.set(eventType, existing);
  }

  public off(eventType: GameEventType, listener: GameEventListener) {
    let existing = this.listenerMap.get(eventType) ?? [];
    if (existing.length) {
      existing = existing.filter((l) => l !== listener);
      this.listenerMap.set(eventType, existing);
    }
  }

  public fireEvent(event: GameEvent) {
    const listeners = this.listenerMap.get(event.type) ?? [];
    listeners.forEach((l) => l(event));
  }
}
```

Consider the above event listener class. When you register an event, you provide the event type you care about and a callback to receive the event object. When firing the event, by giving the `type` property the correct `GameEventType` enum value, it will suggest the other props of that event object. Nice.

What's not so nice is that the consumer still has to ensure the event type is as expected in order to gain access to the other props in the object. Even though the consumer has registered to receive events for `GameEventType.EVENT_ONE`, and even though it will only ever receive an event when that event type is fired, the consumer still has to say `if (event.type === GameEventType.EVENT_ONE)` in order to get to the props in the whole event object.

```
gameObserver.on(GameEventType.EVENT_ONE, (event: GameEvent) => {
  // This won't work - cannot access other props of event object
  console.log(event.parameter)  
  
  // Must do this
  if (event.type === GameEventType.EVENT_ONE) {
    // In order to see the other props linked to that enum value under type
    console.log(event.parameter)
  }
});
```

What I'd really like:

- when registering an event listener via `on` method, it will warn against assigning a callback function whose parameters don't match the props of the event
- when firing the event, it knows the event object props from the event type and auto completes/suggests those prop names as you type
- when consuming, the callback just has the props of the event and not the type (we know the type, we registered this callback against it!) and therefore doesn't have to check the event type in order to get the props

I have managed the latter point in a different fashion, using `any`, which lost out on the first two points (and would prefer to avoid any).

Any advice on this problem would be much appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to make `on`/`off`/`fireEvent` generic in the event type.  The minimum change to your code looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mLl6Zm) but needs at least one `any`.  If you want compiler-verified safety and avoid type assertions, you'll need to significantly refactor so that, among other things, the compiler is aware that your `listenerMap` associates each event type with an array of listeners to handle that event; a `Map` is not appropriate; it's easier to just use a plain old object.  [This approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOP66N) is how I'd write your code to be as safe as possible.

Comment: Does that address your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for replying and writing up those examples @jcalz. From looking at the examples, I prefer the first - I can live with a single 'any', and the second example boils my brain a bit! Both approaches have the same effect on the consumer; the registering and firing of events looks the same either way, so I'd go with your first approach. If you want to write that up I'll accept that as the answer :)

Comment: Okay I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a minimum, you'll want to make the `on()` and `off()` methods [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` of the event, so that the compiler can represent the connection between the first and second arguments.  Let's turn `GameEvent` into `GameEvent<K>`:

```
export type GameEvent<K extends GameEventType> = Extract<
  | { type: GameEventType.EVENT_ONE; parameter: string }
  | { type: GameEventType.EVENT_TWO; anotherParam: SomeType }
  | { type: GameEventType.EVENT_THREE; }, { type: K }>
```

This is using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter the original [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to just the member whose `type` property is `K`.  So a `GameEvent<GameEventType.EVENT_TWO>` will specifically be `{type: GameEvenetType.EVENT_TWO; anotherParam: SomeType}`. And the corresponding change to `GameEventListener` is:

```
type GameEventListener<K extends GameEventType> = 
  (event: GameEvent<K>) => void;
```

Now we can use `K` in `on()` and `off()`:

```
public on<K extends GameEventType>(eventType: K, listener: GameEventListener<K>) {
   // same implementation
}

public off<K extends GameEventType>(eventType: K, listener: GameEventListener<K>) {
   // same implementation
}
```

You can verify that this behaves as desired when you call one of these methods:

```
const gameObserver = new GameObserver()
gameObserver.on(GameEventType.EVENT_ONE, (event) => {
  console.log(event.parameter.toUpperCase()) // okay
});
```

You do have to tweak your other code a bit to deal with these generics.  The trickiest place is in your `listenerMap` property, which uses [a `Map` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).  Unfortunately, a `Map<K, V>` typings for TypeScript gives each property the same type `V` no matter what key in `K` you're using.  The least amount of work but least amount of safety is to give it a type like `Map<GameEventType, GameEventListener<any>[]>` and not worry about potential mismatches:

```
private listenerMap = new Map<GameEventType, GameEventListener<any>[]>();
```

And any other place that refers to `GameEvent` or `GameEventListener` needs to be modified accordingly:

```
public fireEvent<K extends GameEventType>(event: GameEvent<K>) { /*impl */ }
```

That's the "minimum" refactoring, which changes just the typings without changing any runtime code, and gives up some type safety whenever something touches the `listenerMap`.  For example, inside of `on()`, you can replace `get(eventType)` with some specific type like `get(GameEventType.EVENT_THREE)` and the compiler has no idea that there's a problem with that.

```
const existing = this.listenerMap.get(GameEventType.EVENT_THREE) ?? 
  []; // no error, oops
```

---

If you really care about type safety, you can look into [giving a stronger type to `Map`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218), but it's much easier to just use a plain old object type like `{[K in GameEventType]?: GameEventListener<K>[]`, and refactor the other types to be *distributive object types* as coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to deal with correlated generics effectively:

```
interface GameEventMap {
  [GameEventType.EVENT_ONE]: { parameter: string };
  [GameEventType.EVENT_TWO]: { anotherParam: SomeType };
  [GameEventType.EVENT_THREE]: {}
}
type GameEvent<K extends GameEventType> = { [P in K]: GameEventMap[P] & { type: P } }[K]
type GameEventListener<K extends GameEventType> = (event: GameEvent<K>) => void;
type ListenerMap<K extends GameEventType> = { [P in K]?: GameEventListener<K>[] };
```

And then `listenerMap` would be of type `ListenerMap<K>` for any `K` you care about:

```
export class GameObserver {
  private listenerMap: ListenerMap<GameEventType> = {}

  public on<K extends GameEventType>(eventType: K, listener: GameEventListener<K>) {
    const listenerMap: ListenerMap<K> = this.listenerMap;
    let listeners = listenerMap[eventType];
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = [];
      listenerMap[eventType] = listeners;
    }
    listeners.push(listener);
  }

  public off<K extends GameEventType>(eventType: K, listener: GameEventListener<K>) {
    const listenerMap: ListenerMap<K> = this.listenerMap;
    let listeners = listenerMap[eventType];
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = [];
    }
    listeners = listeners.filter(l => l !== listener);
    listenerMap[eventType] = listeners;
  }

  public fireEvent<K extends GameEventType>(event: GameEvent<K>) {
    const listenerMap: ListenerMap<K> = this.listenerMap;
    let listeners = listenerMap[event.type];
    if (!listeners) {
      listeners = [];
    }
    listeners.forEach((l) => l(event));
  }
}
```

That's sort of the "maximum" refactoring, where the compiler will be more able to catch type errors inside your class methods, like the following line analogous to `listenerMap.get(GameEventType.EVENT_THREE)` from before:

```
let listeners = listenerMap[GameEventType.EVENT_THREE]; // error!
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsgLICWwVYArmAEoQBmCALgPYBOehRJBAAeMXhyHBGSAOLgIAUQBuEYBwAqATxjICgwQoBqCgHLqA+gHkTCpAF4kAcggq1AWi7AIjgDQD9RqYW6gDqlvZOLqocbhwA7ly+-gbGZubqABJMCrYOzq4xHAAWPBDeyQC+yRzayADKXJBaOhG4SCAAXEhQHDw0AOZIVfoiYjwSNS1ykMrRADwA0kLCHKoAJlCy8rNqzRAAfBEKKzycc8lEAD54SJMQXdOKBXsAdIFp1goA3Ehwp5CrHhdHp9YCDYb6JDXNp3B7bZ61N6pYJhH4gYBcYoQHgABRA-y6DSatSGFyhN1hWxmCJ0SKC6SyOR+FR8FNqXSWFX2+GqJMeOw4ABkqD1VNjFstVsANlSntE9ocHAAKKJqOHU+YLfYASnshyUXCoay+PJGonESHgGBAUE2j0sACMoNiVHw9JCYH0lCBVkgMCKpdiKCAYBEvHEkMGYHN+TSIKzY9FhaKvDw5ujNPsANoAXX2Su1PwA9EWkHMkG43F4IGtuo0IMUBn6qABrZAZ25FbEQU0e+gO-3wJCeCUiKUyxO7Wr51UadlIBas-0p7HquVqZOBtNa3XuyGWzw9ZYBpsORtQF7LrdRl79BsquO6gD8T6QuZN+6IJYPwCPIhPYIROel4BmKPA3neHBKpOc60u8wSMgoz6vu+SDfhiQg8DwvBkkQ-49AMLwwPQUBFEqV5gYWuGdiKIEruBIYvM6UGznsrL4RwAxUfuVRksRA5UEOXCsKwo4rOsdrwvK04PtJOgckuoGpmuAqbmBiw6vwn5+g2x4EYBZ5FLRFGphB96sbUyFvjmH6flQrBICqwgAf0l6qP0xS7tReHOfpgwOBxhGsFQGCAkq5G6nYhwYEgACEdgOCZ2LcdpNEXklDEwEx5lxuxvmcWCKU8WSvH7vxg5IMFpQCmJ46SRqU46DOBQqQUGledp8CHhIGWbIZxlKUGjGQbJagvHcVnvtRvUvKwvAKAgZERXqfqjRw2pFYIEJEKVghdb+Ej9PIjrOjwrphhAEb2k6LrYgWyRHZAJ23TwLyeNBUmNRAdIfDYrJrZFhx7nth5cBg30YFw-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-hg4G+h9pHiETAfB9FCFamIQNfx5C+E0PonQnxWYREQBstRGRSo5G0IUdpJR1ldFmNSbQwRBjgqhTujFOeMV4raPoqYwQUSYlaLUdiKAujQGCHAUOKqO9oETiATJWcqD3HUS8eE3BvikD-wCRXYCPiMk6X6WBSJZCYDRIKONWocTpEOUSfIzB+g0kqM-LnTZuT5qLXChgQGq1ZwbXqdrZIfSkCPQgM-c6DhwxPxui-HgBYl63PudiN6wAPppxYXzT4-0zkrQ8T+KAYMIZQxhl7AEyVia2SqBUIAA)

Comment: Thanks for writing that up, both suggestions solve the problem nicely and are a good lesson in generics in typescript!

Comment: Hey @jcalz :) It's been a while and the above is still serving me well. Just checking back in with another question - how would you make the above event object and/or enum extendable for consumers?