# Can't assign correlated union to object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to use the "correlated union" changes in TS 4.6 to let me keep some factory functions typed when they're used by a generic factory (and their returned values, which I don't really show below because I already run into trouble with the factory functions).

I can't make it happy with the assignment at the end of [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4gDwBUB8UC8UAFAJQF5YCwAUKJLIiuluBAM4FQDeNUUAZsmQAuKG2CoAlgDsA5ryjAAFjNmiuYyQC8Io6QFcAtgCMIqKAF8aV6jTrQAcnEMQAJvCRpMAaSgQAHsAQ0q4cANYQIMj8DJ7MrByEEVExHkwgLJBseIQ81HwA2gAKUDJQ3gC66gp80s66UEU1AoxeomleGB3xWcUVOAo2FgWVNDQIyNLiLXGS7OpQBQ6l0lDJ0bHpmexVUE4u7q3oGA54Fpx5fIIi3FB1LqIARNePADQz6aKk5FCPKo+WV4KZSqBb3BqPEFyN4fNrEMj4PBEDRsbQNAAsAFYAGyWMgWIHUGz8fTSJCSSZQOCuQ5xTDLAJBELhSIbboZBI4Ij8ABuon2bnZJxwZEusKk7AKvIAdOCKpxedYaEA):

```js
type Factory<T> = () => T
type FactoryTypes = {
  foo: string
  thing: { size: number }
}

type NamedFactory<K extends keyof FactoryTypes = keyof FactoryTypes> = {
  [P in K]: {
    name: P
    factory: Factory<FactoryTypes[P]>
  }
}[K]

const factories: { [N in keyof FactoryTypes]: NamedFactory<N> } = {
  foo: { name: "foo", factory: () => "hi" },
  thing: { name: "thing", factory: () => ({ size: 456 }) },
}
function addFactory<N extends keyof FactoryTypes>(fv: NamedFactory<N>) {
  factories[fv.name] = fv
}
```

That last line gives me:

```
Type 'NamedFactory<N>' is not assignable to type '{ foo: { name: "foo"; factory: Factory<string>; }; thing: { name: "thing"; factory: Factory<{ size: number; }>; }; }[N]'.
  Type '{ name: N; factory: Factory<FactoryTypes[N]>; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    The intersection '{ name: "foo"; factory: Factory<string>; } & { name: "thing"; factory: Factory<{ size: number; }>; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'name' has conflicting types in some constituents.
```

Of course in real code I'd also have some way to call a factory given a name, returning a value returned by one of the named factory functions.

How can I change this code so TS is happy with storing the factory functions in an object, retaining the factory return type information?

Comment: If you want to retain the current API you have the easiest way is to cast to `never`: `factories[fv.name] = fv as never;`. I don't think TypeScript can infer these things yet (maybe in 4.8?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that you are having is caused by the `fv` parameter type not being assignable to the `factory` object's properties. The reason why this is happening is because `NamedFactory` property values' types do not match, so when you attempt to assign a `NamedFactory` type's property - TypeScript attempts to make a `union` out of its property value types (resulting in a type that just contains the `name` property type), and because this union does not apply to the minimum requirements of the `factories` object (as all of its properties contain more than `name`), this argument is no longer applicable - hence it is set to `never`.

The fix is relatively simple, all you need to do is to directly infer the property value type from the `factories` const itself. This can be done by replacing `fv: NamedFactory<N>` with `fv: typeof factories[N]` which will infer the full property value type from `factories` directly and will not have to do the `union` step:

```
function addFactory<N extends keyof FactoryTypes>(fv: typeof factories[N]) {
  factories[fv.name] = fv;
}
```

Playground link [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYghgY2AewE4gDwBUB8UC8UAFAJQF5YCwAUKJLIiuluBAM4FQDeNUUAZsmQAuKG2CoAlgDsA5ryjAAFjNmiuYyQC8Io6QFcAtgCMIqKAF8aV6jTrQAcnEMQAJvCRpMAaSgQAHsAQ0q4cANYQIMj8DJ7MrByEEVExHkwgLJBseIQ81HwA2gAKUDJQ3gC66gp80s66UEU1AoxeomleGB3xWcUVOAo2FgWVNDQIyNLiLXGS7OpQBQ6l0lDJ0bHpmexVUE4u7q3oGA54Fpx5fIIi3FB1LqIARNePADQz6aKk5FCPKo+WV4KZSqBb3BqPEFyN4fNrEMj4PBEDRsbQNAAsAFYAGyWMgWIHUGw0fj6aRISSTKBwVyHOKYZYBIIhcKRDbdDIJHBEfgAN1E9g2-COczYSwqZEusKk7AKfIAdOCKpw+QBuaxjag0unpZF3epPF7vYX0r4IvB-SQAiwkVVAA).

Comment: Thanks, that does resolve the error.  However, right now I'm still unclear whether I've used "correlated unions" (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) without needing to, or why other answers here using correlated unions don't run into this problem (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72192420/typescript-event-listener-type-to-props-mapping/72194737#72194737 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72282435/typescript-how-to-use-generated-union-type-correctly-in-a-loop/72294288#72294288)

Comment: My answer does fix the error you are experiencing in the example as illustrated by the playground link... Nevertheless, the reason why you were experiencing and the person in the stack overflow second link is not (as I can see your example very closely mimics theirs) is because they are assigning primitive variables instead of full objects/function types. E.g. if we added the following line inside the ```addFactory```: ```factories[fv.name].name = fv.name```, it will work just fine. As soon as you introduce objects, that's where problems start to occur.

Comment: Which is when the union is introduced which is what is causing problems