# Prevent type widening on maps

Tags: typescript

Is there some way to have TypeScript understand that the value retrieved from this map is not `undefined`?

```
const stringToDecimal = new Map<string, number>([
    ["one", 1],
    ["two", 2],
]);

console.log(stringToDecimal.get("one") + 5);  // Error about being possibly undefined
```

It seems you can't use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) with Map, and also [`ReadonlyMap`](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es2015_collection_d_.readonlymap.html) didn't work.

Comment: You would either have to use `!` or extend `Map`.

Comment: Here's how extending Map would look like: https://tsplay.dev/WPpqYW

Comment: `Map` is not specific enough for you; as caTS says, you could make your own custom `Map` interface.... like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVbqvN), as mentioned in the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54907009/typescript-how-can-i-make-entries-in-an-es6-map-based-on-an-object-key-value-ty).