# Replacing deeply nested values in a JSON with a value of a different type, while maintaining type-safety?

Tags: typescript, type-conversion, type-mapping

I wrote a function that takes as input a JSON object and a Map defining values to be replaced; and returns the same JSON object with all the occurrences of values replaced by the corresponding replacements -- which can be anything.

This changes the type of the object, but I cannot figure out how to reflect this change in TypeScript.

Here is the function:

```
function replaceJsonValues<Source, Replacement, Output>(
  obj: Source,
  translatedKeyData: Map<string, Replacement>
): Output {
  let stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify(obj);
  for (const [key, keyProp] of translatedKeyData.entries()) {
    stringifiedObject = stringifiedObject.replaceAll(`"${key}"`, JSON.stringify(keyProp));
  }
  return JSON.parse(stringifiedObject);
}

type SourceType = {
  foo: string; 
  baz: { 
    test: string;
  } 
}[]


type ReplacementType = {
  fancy: string;
}

const source: SourceType = [{ foo: "bar", baz: { test: "bar" } }];
const replacement: ReplacementType = { fancy: "replacement" };

const result = replaceJsonValues(source, new Map([["bar", replacement]]));
//    ^?


console.log(result)
```

See in TS [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYAcA2BDCqBSAzggGraYiqEA8AynCMngDSIBKGOeAtqmFKwDyIKOhEA%20ABQAoRIjgAjAFYAuRPUYtZiKMmxhCOKKgAmAaVQBPACLYo2NQFls6aoV0wwAc1YcsuVF5%20cWkASjVhURFEAG9tTFQoRHdkTy8YYBhTQWVUaEQAXkR8WkEAOQA6FLSMy0lFJVCAbm1gOGRESQgEd0QAbQBrK1YhywAFZDh0AF15YB09AyNTCxs7bAq%20DypJUNDY7Tlq7wyskxylPKSi4-TM7NzoCrR-PABBTExJAAMAIgASGKjAC%20v2%20rBK5SqHhOwDqowmUz2LTkwO0aCgjCQkMq6GwyEIqEkt1OD0u0Ga0jR0iglnQqHUDCYqAAKnSGUU4nI2nA1LcmohtApsAAvNQxQVyOTGdx8mFeFGIYGC4F9abSDW0%20nsTgBIJQNnazmtfQQSxy1LeFrU7oGJLETSoNQaZmGjn9CU8tS-YXIX6sYVi2I6KhQb2%2035KpXTFq23ovLiBLZqPyJ-VuwrB4Cm82IX4JvVbSPAlrSONJNCEECYa4oXV4IikciUQjEpksRBgVAAd0QznQkj6fR9%20P9ddeSf402myOkAHo51LEAA9AD8GrLPTgCQqmDgXkklerUH2QA).

How do I modify this so that the `Output` type is correct?

Comment: Oh my goodness, why are you doing string replacement operations on JSON?  Like, what should `replaceJsonValues({ a: "\"what" }, new Map([["what", {}]])))` do (it actually explodes)?  It's vaguely possible someone could write a type operation that represents what I think you're going for, but only with huge caveats about how parsing JSON yourself is A Very Bad Idea

Comment: Like, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG4X0w) is the closest I can imagine.  I'm happy to write up an answer showing how it works, but I'd really stress that you shouldn't be using JSON strings for this purpose; it would be far safer to iterate objects normally, perhaps like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgAK1m) shows.  Do you want to see either of these written up? How should we proceed here?

Comment: thanks @jcalz, both examples are a great help to me :) I used the stringify approach because I generate the replacement data, so I am fairly sure it will not break the JSON object.. true I could add some extra check on the format of the source object to make sure things like your example cannot happen..

complexity-wise, are the two approaches similar? I don't really know what magic goes on in JSON.stringify and parse..

Comment: there is something weird when using the function, though.. or maybe I am doing something wrong? [see this example](https://tsplay.dev/WPzBEN) where I added a `useTheReplacementFunction` -- ALL strings become ReplacementType

Comment: You more or less told the compiler that `translatedSdsProps` has a `ReplacementType` value at every `string` key; such annotations only confuse things.  Not sure why you didn't write [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV7rnm) instead.  Anyway, that seems like a followup question since it's not part of your original example or the question post, so I'm not going to worry too much about addressing it.   Should I write up an answer explaining how my solution works?

Comment: yes please @jcalz, I still do not understand why the solution only works when using "as const".. what if `translatedSdsProps` is generated dynamically inside the `useTheReplacementFunction` method? I can create a follow-up question for that :)

Comment: .. writing that comment I realised the absurdity of what I am asking. of course I cannot pass a runtime generate object and expect the compiler to know the types.. maybe I can mark somehow the translatable keys in the input object type.. I will think about it and create a follow-up. 

still, it would be nice if you could write an answer explaining the recursion in the type mapping :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues to get out of the way:

- I assume you care about the particular relationship between the key/value pairs in `translatedKeyData`.  If so, you can't easily use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to do this.  In TypeScript, `Map` is typed as `Map<K, V>`, a record-like type in which all the keys are considered to be the same type as each other, and all the values are considered to be the same type as each other... any association between a particular key and a particular value will be lost.  There are ways to change the typing of `Map` so that it does keep track of such connections, as described in [Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218), but it would be much easier to use a plain object to start with.  Instead of `new Map([["k1", v1], ["k2", v2], ...])` you would use `{k1: v1, k2: v2, ...}`.  Instead of using [the `entries()` method of `Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries), you could just use [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
- I would strongly recommend against performing string manipulation on JSON strings, as it is incredibly easy to accidentally produce invalid JSON this way. Consider

  ```
  replaceJsonValues({ a: "b", c: "d" }, new Map([[",", "oops"]])); 
  //  RUNTIME ERROR! parsing "{"a":"b"oops"c":"d"}"
  ```

  for example. Since you start and end with JavaScript values, you can perform a conceptually identical transformation by just walking through objects themselves, so that you are sure that you are only replacing string-valued keys or string-values values, and not weird pieces of things.  The algorithm would look like:

  ```
  function replaceValues(obj: any, translatedKeyData: any) {
    if (typeof obj === "string") {
      return (obj in translatedKeyData) ? translatedKeyData[obj] : obj;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj.map(v => replaceValues(v, translatedKeyData));
    }
    if (obj && typeof obj === "object") {
      return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [
        ((k in translatedKeyData) &&
          typeof translatedKeyData[k] === "string"
        ) ? translatedKeyData[k] : k,
        replaceValues(v, translatedKeyData)]
      ));
    }
    return obj;
  }
  ```
- Finally, this will only possibly work if the compiler knows the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of all the string values to replace on both the source `obj` and the mapping `translatedKeyData`.  If any of these are widened to `string`, then the replacement will not be properly typed.  That means you need to know the details of both the source and the mapping at compile time.  If they are only known at runtime, then your options will be very limited. I will assume that you have compile-time known values, and that these values will be initialized with [`const` assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to give the maximum information to the compiler.

---

Okay, now for the typings:  I would do something like this:

```
function replaceValues<S, M extends object>(
  obj: S,
  translatedKeyData: M
): ReplaceValues<S, M>;

type ReplaceValues<S, M extends object> =
  S extends keyof M ? M[S] :
  S extends readonly any[] ? {
    [I in keyof S]: ReplaceValues<S[I], M>
  } :
  S extends object ? {
    [K in keyof S as (
      K extends keyof M ? M[K] extends string ? M[K] : K : K
    )]:
    ReplaceValues<S[K], M>
  } :
  S;
```

So the source object is of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `S`, and the mapping object is of generic type `M`, and then the return type is `ReplaceValues<S, M>`, a [recursive conditionalt type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) which goes through the different cases for `S` and performs replacements accordingly.

First: `S extends keyof M ? M[S]` means that if the source `S` is a key in `M`, then you can just replace `S` with the corresponding property `M[S]` from `M`.  That's the straight string value replacement: the type level version of the `typeof obj === "string"` code block in the implementation.

Then: `S extends readonly any[] ? { [I in keyof S]: ReplaceValues<S[I], M> } :` means that if the source `S` is an arraylike type, then we [map that arraylike type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to another arraylike type where each value is replaced recursively.  That's the type level version of the `Array.isArray(obj)` code block in the implementation.

Then: `S extends object ? { [K in keyof S as ( K extends keyof M ? M[K] extends string ? M[K] : K : K )]: ReplaceValues<S[K], M> } :` means that if the source `S` is a non-array object, then we [map the keys and values](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) of the object so that any keys found in `M` are remapped, while recursively applying `ReplaceValues` to each value type.  That's the type level version of the `(obj && typeof obj === "object")` code block in the implementation.

Finally, if all those are false, then we return `S`.  That is falling through the bottom, so that numbers stay numbers, and booleans stay booleans, etc.  This is the type level version of the `return obj` at the bottom of the implementation.

---

Okay, let's see if it works:

```
const source = [{ foo: "bar", baz: { test: "bar" }, qux: 123 }] as const;
const replacement: ReplacementType = { fancy: "replacement" };

const result = replaceValues(source, { bar: replacement, qux: "foop" } as const);
/* const result: readonly [{
    readonly foo: ReplacementType;
    readonly baz: {
        readonly test: ReplacementType;
    };
    readonly foop: 123;
}] */
```

Looks good! The compiler replaces the `"bar"` values with `ReplacementType`, and it replaces the `"qux"` key with `"foop"`.  That corresponds perfectly to the object that actually comes out at runtime:

```
console.log(result);
/* [{
  "foo": {
    "fancy": "replacement"
  },
  "baz": {
    "test": {
      "fancy": "replacement"
    }
  },
  "foop": 123
}] */
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAJwKYAcA2BDCqBq2mIqAzgDwDKANIgLKKoAeUqYAJqYnAEYBWqaAD4AFAChE3fgC5ENCYijJsYUjlbsA0qgCeAEWxRssumICUsgEoYceQsTJVadIQG4xoSLAQobuAkQkpCK8fLIqOrRKKmqGqFq6BkbhYDpmiADeCjDAiCJQOuiocLmhiAC8lYgARKRKMGAA5tXpWZKSaFAgyEgh-IgNisqq6vHa+obY6QD8QzGjCRNGANqhALqIsqHukgC+2bkiAILIyjoAdDCkJ2d9fGatCh2oXT1SfOcAttjoIgBuFSEviw-nsQX+UWGsQ04ySUzMO0Q+0kOTyZQAZOjFIViqV+pVyjVQoIoC1Mk9fK8kAB5fgk87AZBwT4AUTA9TIIlpAmg5zYHOCoTMXx+IhEywA1rQ-mt0uUgcsKZIxRKBkhoiM4os4elMUr2gUiiU5pqYYlJpKNgSanVkA1mvqZiboWNzSsJRtZFL9WgQXZApy-pD5lrYZMzGsKQ9EcjKd0kNsxPsxIbUIhrH6Ag4KDR6IwWGxOO8SUDygpKPnWBwuBLdMaGLM6MtKJ7y5XC1w0Nh2AhMDpEBFlhtZm12ssAJJqxC1nTGltWPz+7NUCdrZxCBS7TZt5hVovE6CIEcU5aaKczucDrjidrtM+7jvTuu5Bv0U8bB-VxC2+1Ht+aT1EDPWRNCjNZpApDNbCzIIVwA9dN23SRKHcFMcXTRdUE+fkABV0MJUdgBUCAdFkH8mncZMxAgBA6m-OBujwCpEGWDJEGAOA4FkaoeGwZBqloXiAC9ZDY1g6m43j+KRWgAEcQCYWQAEYACYAGYkQ2bAuBo1QoHcXS6N9aDsPZBdM1MqA8KKZi2KIyBSJqYz-Es6okVQwyoF8UgQEwLzCWcpdwVIBjkDwWg2Kk2RAqw-k5IU7iOLgdA3K3bTEE8hExAAegAKgy2ivLQHy-Oi1Bu17ftWIpLsezAPt2M48yTNwnFEWeCr6v7YTRP1Dq6oa8SoGalzWqKdr3Jq8qBv7JL0GU9TKI2XLsrENbDLgTBUHOTA4EaERit8qAsryljR2qJLql628LuInQrqczDXM3agFB47AhIe0dJGqIavv1W6HIe6oYue29Y12V6frmh7VLUpNltWtagA)