# new Map() with strict key and value types

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am new to TypeScript, normally we can do somethin like this:

```
interface IPerson {
    name: string,
    age: number
}

const tim:IPerson = {
    name: 'Tim',
    age: 21
}
```

above codes, "tim" object **need** to include `name`(with string value) and `age`(with number value) properties.

So my question is, can I do the same thing with `new Map()`? (like the codes above, must include `name`(name value must be string) and `age`(age value must be number) properties.)

I did tried creating some generic Interfaces and types but I don't think I am doing it right, because none of the work.

Comment: TS doesn't have built-in typings for this; you could write them yourself, but it's not clear what advantage this has over a plain object. See [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218) for more info; if I use the code in there with your example I get [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXOjoW).