# How to avoid switch cases in typescript when switching over discriminators?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I want to refactor the following code in a way, that gets rids of the switch case, but preserves type safety. I've found me in multiple situations where this problem occurred.
Is there a pattern to use a map or something else than a switch case?

```
function translate(when: When): SomeCommonResultType {
  switch (when.object) {
    case "timespan":
      return translateTimeSpan(when);
    case "time":
      return translateTime(when);
    case "datespan":
      return translateDateSpan(when);
    case "date":
      return translateDate(when);
  }
}

type When = Timespan | Time | DateSpan | Date;

export interface Timespan {
  readonly object: "timespan";
  startTime: number;
  endTime: number;
  startTimezone?: string;
  endTimezone?: string;
}

function translateTimeSpan(when: Timespan): SomeCommonResultType {
  ...
}

export interface Time {
  readonly object: "time";
  time: number;
  timezone: string;
}

function translateTime(when: Time): SomeCommonResultType {
  ...
}

export interface DateSpan {
  readonly object: "datespan";
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}

function translateDateSpan(when: DateSpan): SomeCommonResultType {
  ...
}

export interface Date {
  readonly object: "date";
  date: string;
}

function translateDate(when: Date): SomeCommonResultType {
  ...
}
```

Normaly I would do something like the following, but I really don't want to use 'any'

```
const TranslateWhenMap = new Map<string, any>([
  ["timespan", translateTimeSpan],
  ["date", translateDate],
  ["datespan", translateDateSpan],
  ["time", translateTime],
]);

function translate(when: When): SomeCommonResultType {
  return TranslateWhenMap.get(when.object)(when);
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NaDRnw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, this matches my expectations.

Nontheless I don't think the solution is practical for evey day usage.
But I don't see a way around the complexety without building a small function wrapping away the complexety...

Comment: I don't understand, how is my suggestion any more impractical than the version you wrote with "normally I would do something like the following"?  It's almost the same.  I'm happy to write up an answer but I'm confused about the issue around practicality/complexity.

Comment: I understand your confusion and I don't mean that your answer is bad in any way, it's great. 

The Pattern that is needed to make the approach type safe is just, way more complicated to learn, apply and recognize than the factory or builder pattern. I am actually trying to wrap this stuff into a creator function, but I'm not the biggest fan of introducing such "framework-functions". I think an _excellent_ pattern should just use the built in tools of the language. So this is complaining on a high level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler can only really type check a block of code once; it can't look at `TranslateWhenMap.get(when.object)(when)` where `when` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and understand that `when` will be the appropriate argument to the `TranslateWhenMap.get(when.object)` function, even if a `Map` had strongly typed key-value relationships (which it doesn't, see [Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218) ).  It can't enumerate the possible types of `when` and check each one separately, like  "if `when` is a `TimeSpan` then it's fine; if `date` is a `TimeSpan` then it's fine; etc".  It does it "all at once" and will get confused.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).

The only way to get type checking for multiple cases in a single block of code is to refactor to make your `translate()` function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and write the operations such that the compiler sees that the generic parameter type to the looked-up up function is the same generic type as `when`.  The general approach to refactoring for situations like this is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), although the case here doesn't quite need all of the machinery listed there.

Here's how I'd approach your example:

```
type WhenObject = When["object"];
type TranslateArg<K extends WhenObject> = Extract<When, { object: K }>;

const translateWhenMap: { [K in WhenObject]: 
  (arg: TranslateArg<K>) => SomeCommonResultType 
} = {
  timespan: translateTimeSpan,
  date: translateDate,
  datespan: translateDateSpan,
  time: translateTime
}

function translate<K extends WhenObject>(when: TranslateArg<K>) {
  const obj: K = when.object;
  return translateWhenMap[obj](when);
}
```

The `WhenObject` utility type is just the union of `object` property types of `When`, implemented as an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  And the  `TranslateArg<K>` utility type evaluates to the union member of `When` whose `object` property matches `K`, implemented via [the TS-provided `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union).

I've then replaced your `Map` with a plain strongly-typed `translateWhenMap` object, where the compiler knows the relationship between each key and value. (e.g., the `timespan` key has a function expecting a `Timespan` argument, etc.)  And I explicitly [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) that object as being written in terms of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `WhenObject`. This explicit type is important because it allows the function lookup to remain generic in `K`.

Finally, the `translate()` function is generic in `K` [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `WhenObject`, and `when` is of type `TranslateArg<K>`.  Then inside the function I widen `when.object` to the generic type `K` (left on its own, the compiler will see it as equivalent to `K & WhenObject` which confuses it) and assign to `obj`.  And then the call `translateWhenMap[obj](when)` compiles without error.  `transalteWhenMap[obj]` is seen as being of type `(arg: TranslateArg<K>) => SomeCommonResultType`, and since `when` is of type `TranslateArg<K>`, the call succeeds.

---

That's about as type safe as it's possible to get here.  If you modify the entries of `translateWhenMap` or the implementation of `translate`, you should get errors telling you what you did wrong:

```
const badTranslateWhenMap: { [K in WhenObject]: (arg: TranslateArg<K>) => SomeCommonResultType } = {
  timespan: translateDateSpan, // error
  date: translateDate,
  datespan: translateTimeSpan, // error
  time: translateTime
}

function badTranslate<K extends WhenObject>(when: TranslateArg<K>) {
  const obj: K = when.object;
  const badWhen: Date = { object: "date", date: "Next Thursday" };
  return translateWhenMap[obj](badWhen); // error!
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvATEg3gLABQSSoksCyamWBJZZAlsAC4QBOAZtUgMoB7SAGFhYQcABK0AK4Y2AFQCeMZEVJMyIAFxIobTqwDmAbkZMAviQtk2q5AHUAFhGBIAvEkXNKcdwA+3r7IQQAiIBz8-kjhkRDmxLZI9mpILm4A8gBGAFYQ8Gye6a7AANoARIJ5BWwVALqJWqnIipwgwFAY8QCCnMYAPADSSBAAHhzAACZQJVk1hQB8xQCiE+2FAxnAADQESNX5hXojlouJyfCSBintnd0c2wCyIDB6+EhlI6xzwDlHbHqegAFCB+no2h0ur1+sNFgBKTzLISicSSGRQeRKBxISzFDRaOwhKjAPSGKEPCA+SDRDo7ZJkKbxMl3aEcCIcemaLRMjgklkU+IciC03YMlIhAX3eLUiDJaxJblIbiyYCFZiSW6CjjDUYTNwzX7-WqLYEAd1KENZlL6gyGCIYSrIV06RUOJ2KFrcADpDrUmoTOBA2LJOO5ydLHqUXjAyod6ubSvCA2QFTYlRG2RBgR8-cckBVeRAKnsi3oKiBsvAKrjk0gAPT1g4AaxAynTWhdN2yICmkMjEGer3en2+7m2xsKQKQoPB3mtMLtDo8yOEEDEYAk0jkChUaTxXgJhLYxP8UqzwtFe0bo04nEEnHFZa1A+FXMJSCL-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)