# strongly typed Map Entries typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a map in Typescript of events to their corresponding event handlers in a strongly typed way.

```
class EventA extends Event {}
class EventB extends Event {}

function handleA(eventA: EventA): void {}
function handleB(eventB: EventB): void {}

// help me with typing EventToHandlerMap

// I want this to pass
const map: EventToHandlerMap = new Map([
  [EventA, handleA],
  [EventB, handleB]
]);

// I want this to fail
const map: EventToHandlerMap = new Map([
  [EventA, handleB],
  [EventB, handleA]
]);
```

Is there a way to model a relationship between the key and value in every entry of the Map

Comment: you are mixing both key types and value types

Comment: @Mulan whoops I got the terminology wrong. So put in a proper way, I want to know how I can have a type that relates the key and value in each entry of the Map

Comment: There's no built in way to do this, you'd need to write a fairly complicated version of the Map interface typing as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N5xo0w).  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Also note I added structure to `EventA` and `EventB` otherwise they would be structurally identical to each other and therefore indistinguishable to TS's type system)

Comment: @jcalz Thank you so much for the playground link. It helped a lot. I did a small typo in my question. I need to map the class definition to its handler rather than instance. Think you can help with that? Sorry for the mistake. I'll update the question now

Comment: Okay then does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Nr9k1w) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer, otherwise, what's wrong with it?

Comment: yes, I think your type cast solution does it very well. The only note I have is that I think the `ObjectToEntries` variable isn't used anywhere in the playground. Aside from that, it works as expected. Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah I'll get rid of that, it was from a different solution.  I'll write up an error when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218)  and the answer here is similar to my answer there, but they are different enough that this question and answer isn't a direct duplicate.

---

The TypeScript typings for [`Map<K, V>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) don't reflect any more specific relationship between keys and values than "the keys are of type `K` and the values are of type `V`".  If you need something more specific, you'll need to write your own typings for it.  That involves looking at [the library files](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/4bf047680045a295e505177c5a66c186a48bccc6/src/lib/es2015.collection.d.ts#L1C6-L29) and modifying them.

In your case you want each key to be an `Event` constructor like

```
type EventCtor<T extends Event> = new (...args: any) => T;
```

and each value to be a handler for the corresponding event like

```
type Handler<T extends Event> = (event: T) => void;
```

So we will need to write an `EventToHandlerMap` that behaves like some more specific version of `EventToHandlerMap<EventCtor<any>, Handler<any>>`:

```
interface EventToHandlerMap {
  forEach(callbackfn: <T extends Event>(
    value: Handler<T>, key: EventCtor<T>, map: EventToHandlerMap
  ) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
  get<T extends Event>(key: EventCtor<T>): Handler<T> | undefined;
  set<T extends Event>(key: EventCtor<T>, value: Handler<T>): this;
  readonly size: number;
}
```

That hopefully works how you need it; `get()` and `set()` for example are [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T extends Event` so that the key and value are related.

Then we'll need to define the `Map` constructor in a similar way, so that the compiler knows how to interpret the constructor arguments:

```
interface EventToHandlerMapConstructor {
  new <T extends Event[]>(
    entries: [...{ [I in keyof T]: [k: EventCtor<T[I]>, v: Handler<T[I]>] }]
  ): EventToHandlerMap;
  new(): EventToHandlerMap;
  readonly prototype: EventToHandlerMap;
}

const EventToHandlerMap = Map as EventToHandlerMapConstructor;
```

Note how I've just made `EventToHandlerMap` an alias of `Map` and [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that it behaves as an `EventToHandlerMapConstructor`.  That assertion is necessary because the compiler doesn't know that `Map` will work that way.

Once we do that, you can use `EventToHandlerMap` as your constructor and get the desired behavior:

```
const map: EventToHandlerMap = // okay
  new EventToHandlerMap([[EventA, handleA], [EventB, handleB]]);

const map2: EventToHandlerMap =
  new EventToHandlerMap([[EventA, handleB], [EventB, handleA]]); // error
  //                              ~~~~~~~  <-------> ~~~~~~~
  // Type '(eventB: EventB) => void' is not assignable to type 'Handler<EventA>'.
  // Type '(eventA: EventA) => void' is not assignable to type 'Handler<EventB>'.

map.get(EventA)?.(new EventA("")); // okay
map.get(EventB)?.(new EventB("")); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiBuBTAdgFwILUQD1SgJjAiqtAN4BQ00Y0AvNAIwUC+FokRSaAQlrgS4lyVaACN60AEysKFAGYBXZMFQBLAPbJoACzDJ8IROgAUibhgBccC+gCU1+BrX4R1YFogajAOhAaAczNbHzA7WSUVdS1dfUNEHmCSHmtiXgdoJxc3aA9kL19-IPNknzFwtgpUAE8AB0QbEgBhVA0AJwAeABV+PAMhNAA+SWREAHdoEx9psDaAiGt9art6Ya6Abiq6hoAJOKNOnpw+wkahySS0ay6VumGs-E21NEQ2+TBgBrTULo09gwOAFkwLUcvJ2rAPjoTMAwCAQGIPgBreTIazdXqCM6oQYmUTUeBwxSIaz-eKHQYAGmgSMQ1VSFha7W6VOgAFsQQySL8yUCQaJbvdnPhqagdGoIOg5gB+RbIZaOYWbagBRCoDHHLHfXG0+nYpkUjK814s6AAH2gynwiHkz0Qj1EEDVGoE-WxOrpXLQBpZ1MJIGJpP2Jq6gwyYolyugbUQYHwWhA1WgEDUAC8SdBkIo2WJXptKs88G8Pl8LDzg21gbUmp5UG1FKp2jlRhMXScBqgANoAXVx+KwaDaakQC2gnemPjIY4AktBnjS6Rp5NAut3rJ2kV7UD6up3p72-UGASG973u9AWN2BVvy8fKyCoy2TBlvrfyVWozG4wmk7U2hpWhqeobz+CsP1kdha2xN8+VBBgqxoDsYNeKsa3yOsG1aNpNjkSD0PZTloNAu8EIYAB6MjoA0JEwGqUQWyI4171qExO07b50GpPRj3QbtqXYiweC44MeG7bs7BwvIIFIDlaikECmNI+jxkYsCQVYgSSE42Jj1E-jviEnT4l48T1mgCisDaf82lECzqHshzHKc5zqAAP3cjzXOoDoAFo-P8nzhk8jzbMorptmgAByS5UBSbEeEFTJhUiucYGQADEJTAJkDAMQjGgVoCoiyKmI6DjBkinxQpXYqYvQLd7FWJKXBSiVMwyzg1Gy3L8sKoCGhKisysEiqqooWSfFVVATA4uxpR8EwGI4kwACIVrsCTzMo5gJqmmbBLmhalsE1b1s2iypCAA)