# Using discriminate unions with Map objects

Tags: typescript

Consider this working typescript example that uses discriminated unions:

```js
type Alpha = { name: "alpha"; alpha: 1}
type Beta = { name: "beta"; beta: 2}
type Letters = Alpha | Beta

const calculateAlpha = (cfg: Alpha): number => {
    return cfg.alpha
}
const calculateBeta = (cfg: Beta): number => {
    return cfg.beta
}

const CalculatorFactory1 = (cfg: Letters) => {
  switch (cfg.name) {
    case "alpha":
      return () => calculateAlpha(cfg)
    case "beta":
      return () => calculateBeta(cfg)
    default:
      throw new Error()
  }
}
```

I want to refactor this to make it more configurable by moving the switch statement into a map object. Something like this:

```js
type LetterMap = Map<Letters["name"], (c: Letters) => number>
const letterMap: LetterMap = new Map([
    ["alpha", calculateAlpha],
    ["beta", calculateBeta]
])

const CalculatorFactory2 = (cfg: Letters) => {
    const func = letterMap.get(cfg.name)
    return func(cfg)        
}
```

However I can't figure out how to type `letterMap`, in this example I get the following error:

```
Property 'alpha' is missing in type 'Beta' but required in type 'Alpha'.
```

[Typescript Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQDZQBYEM4F44G84B26AtjAFxwBE6KGlA3HDWuhQIwC+okscAQjDCYc+IqQqUARoPQM40oRQBMXcNHgAZQWBgAnAM7ZEtTAB9+M0KADGAewL6wcazWsBXJOh3IWRgBTWAGYA5hQ+GACUFARuxNK62AB8eKBwaXC6gm66BM4hAHTMGKCqdg5OLkjunjoCQv5BoRZCUYSx8UkpIOkZWTl5wfkK6CVWIGWOcADCrh5etroAYujWYAsQbA0hFFpgOgYRnbipcPoA7gCWYNaocAEFYjCHx93pLvrw1CaUZCc9mWBsrk-IcsMlKtUvDBwuh7sEIn9nOgPlRhj9EWkAUC7qDwbMajA6rDGgjXmkACYwQLoDxgX5k9JgVC6WxnQgwNkAUV0LN0IJOqlU3HUcF2+wAsugoEZJVAADxivT6ADalEelAAugAaO7WHbaJW4tpxPSJGz2SZIA26WX6vZ6WVGAgcuCyvzKxGqoqyHUQubeEzaz1SGSUX34qFEjWgDWksYTJwzKr+hbLVbrJRbJqKg5HREJuCBNwEaxGK32m1S-LBQRw-KPUn-Pq5IsluGHHrpUYgIA)

Comment: "*I want to refactor this to make it more configurable*" - what do you mean by "configurable"?

Comment: It's a reasonably contrived example. Ultimately I want to be able to pass `letterMap` into the `CalculatorFactory2` function so that I can do dependency injection in tests

Comment: Don't use a `Map` that contains `(c: Letters) => number` functions, use `{[k in Letters["name"]]: (c: Letters & {name: k}) => number}`

Comment: Imo you should just use OOP and add a `.calculate(): number` method to the `Letters` interface

Comment: In that scenario, given some data I'd still need a way to construct a `Letter` object from it, which I think brings us back to this scenario i.e. it feels like a chicken and egg problem

Comment: I like the proposed solution but doesn't quite work, see https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQDZQBYEM4F44G84B26AtjAFxwBE6KGlA3HDWuhQIwC+okscAQjDCYc+IqQqUARoPQM40oRQBMXcNHgAZQWBgAnAM7ZEtTAB9+M0KADGAewL6wcazWsBXJOh3IWRgBTWAGYA5hQ+GACUFARuxNK62AB8eKBwaXC6gm66BM4hAHTMGKCqdg5OLkjunjoCQv5BoRZCUYSx8UkpIOkZWTl5wfkK6CVWarxaYDq6ALLoUEa4ANoA1nAAlrmT0-pLlGIwlAC6RxQBFNt6hgBkeAcUKxwRnTFxeqX2jnBI2npzUBdfrN5otUlQirIKJVql4YOF0AAaMFSGSUKGuDywuojECqMZlL4AYQxNVsugAYuhrGAyRAlA0QoCpldnlhkrgwWkCU5Am4CNYjD9mcCoEtGvkDkdOb0wNlcrz+QEQs8eulRiAgA

Comment: This kind of works but isn't pretty https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAQQDZQBYEM4F44G84B26AtjAFxwBE6KGlA3HDWuhQIwC+okscAQjDCYc+IqQqUARoPQM40oRQBMXcNHgAZQWBgAnAM7ZEtTAB9+M0KADGAewL6wcazWsBXJOh3IWRgBTWAGYA5hQ+GACUFARuxNK62AB8eKBwaXC6gm66BM4hAHTMGKCqdg5OLkjunjoCQv5BoRZCUYSx8UkpIOkZWTl5wfkK6CVWarxaYDq6ALLoUEZzUAA8k9P6ANqUYjCUALoANHABFGt6+hGdMXF6ifQ29o5wSNp6S6evs-NGBDAA7nAln4Nql0lsirIjic4GcDJcsMkAOQQxFwACWuWscAA-M5XB4vDBwugAq0AAyHUFpLbDShQ6wfKbneFI4aojHOHF4qoE2oyUlwCgUg6gPYRe4gMZlJ4AYXxNVsugAYuhrGBFRAlA0Qoz1iyuj1pU5Am4CFicC8mV8oPlgoIAgUdhEqb0wNlciazQBCB3BZ0gVRAA

Comment: You can have a discriminated union and polymorphism at the same time.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mb339W) meet your needs?  The problem you're running into is essentially [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended fix is a refactoring described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining fully. If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, TypeScript doesn't by default recognize that a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) could be strongly typed so that each key corresponds to a different value *type*.  A `Map<K, V>` is like [`Record<K, V>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) in that it treats all values as the *same* type.  There are ways to try to encode different value types for `Map` in the type system (see [Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218)) but it's much, much easier to just use a plain object, since [object types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#object-types) naturally represent such key-value type pairs.  So let's make `letterMap` as a plain object like

```
const letterMap = {
    alpha: cfg => cfg.alpha,
    beta: cfg => cfg.beta
}
```

and work on how to use it the way you'd like.

---

TypeScript doesn't really support the concept of "correlated [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)". If you have a value `cfg` of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type `Letters`, and look up `cfg.name` in your `letterMap` map you will get a union of functions.  And then if you try to call that union of functions by passing it `cfg` as an argument, the compiler will be unhappy.  It doesn't understand that the union of functions and the union of arguments are *correlated* to each other such that the function and argument are appropriate for each other.  Instead it treats them as independent unions, and therefore complains that you might be calling `calculateAlpha` with an `Beta` argument, or `calculateBeta` with an `Alpha` argument.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) for more information.

The recommended approach to deal with correlation unions, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), is to refactor to replace the union with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).  The technique involves encoding the underlying relationship you need the compiler to track as a base interface, and then writing operations on this type as [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into this interface or [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that interface.

In your case, the base interface looks like this:

```
interface LetterMapping {
    alpha: { alpha: 1 },
    beta: { beta: 2 }
}
```

And then we can redefine your `Letters` type as a mapped type over it:

```
type Letter<K extends keyof LetterMapping = keyof LetterMapping> =
    { [P in K]: { name: P } & LetterMapping[P] }[K]
```

This is a *distributive object type*, so `Letter<"alpha">` and `Letter<"beta">` correspond to your original `Alpha` and `Beta` types:

```
type Alpha = Letter<"alpha">;
type Beta = Letter<"beta">;
```

and `Letter<"alpha" | "beta">` corresponds to your original `Letters` discriminated union type (and we can just write `Letter` for that, since `"alpha" | "beta"` is the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) type argument).

Now `letterMap`'s type needs to be explicitly [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as another mapped type over `LetterMapping`:

```
const letterMap: { [K in keyof LetterMapping]:
    (cfg: Letter<K>) => number } = {
    alpha: cfg => cfg.alpha,
    beta: cfg => cfg.beta
}
```

And now we can write `calculatorFactory` as a generic function like this:

```
const calculatorFactory = <K extends keyof LetterMapping>(
    cfg: Letter<K>
) => letterMap[cfg.name](cfg); // okay
```

Here the compiler sees `cfg.name` as having the non-union generic type `K`.  And because `letterMap`'s annotated type is a mapped type over the base interface, when we look up `letterMap[cfg.name]` we get the non-union generic type `(cfg: Letter<K>) => number`.  And this function expects an argument of type `Letter<K>`, which is exactly the type of `cfg`.  So `letterMap[cfg.name](cfg)` compiles with no error, and is seen to be of type `number`, as desired.

And callers will also see reasonable behavior:

```
calculatorFactory({ name: "alpha", alpha: 1 });
/* <"alpha">(cfg: { name: "alpha"; } & { alpha: 1; }) => number */
calculatorFactory({ name: "beta", beta: 2 });
/* <"beta">(cfg: { name: "beta"; } & { beta: 2; }) => number */
```

Here the compiler is able to infer that `K` is `"alpha"` for the first call and `"beta"` for the second.  They both return `number`, so in some sense it doesn't matter, but you could imagine changing the functions so that the return type was also looked up in a base interface:

```
interface LetterReturn {
    alpha: boolean,
    beta: string
}

const letterMap: { [K in keyof LetterMapping]:
    (cfg: Letter<K>) => LetterReturn[K] } = {
    alpha: cfg => Math.random() < (cfg.alpha / 2),
    beta: cfg => cfg.beta.toFixed(2)
}

const a = calculatorFactory({ name: "alpha", alpha: 1 });
/* const a: boolean */
const b = calculatorFactory({ name: "beta", beta: 2 });
/* const b: string */
```

which is nice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAeQE4EsDmKDewKxKWIALlBgGZKoAyU5lGAsmHHGXoSXymAA2cABZgAXAQHCxkgIwoAvgBoi-YgCMmEqVvI6ATErXFFwEynIBPOAyYsAPAGkUUAB6UQAExgoA1lBWAPbUKIzMVOyc3CgAvP6BIWH2kRxcIDgAfHEWfPgoANoACqQgKE4AupL54NCSJYooAGTJEWxp3MUVSgWV5nwA9AOkocEAriggUFBeliKwUBbWtigAgjJgca2OAERComA7mQDcSzaoAELaW+G7eocn-SSIQSAw5CiCKe1w1YUuZASwVCt1S0QyVVyJAAFIhqDhJKCMM5MgBKOLZEBjCBaDBKLa8dTSA6SOF4WLZMkAOn2YlURJQ91J8IxKGp9wsZgsLzeH0QQkQY0EYHIQQwADEkKKMFYts5XB4oN5fAFgdswekstCocQyYjviiLOiKZ9vlECtTalAKrD4ajjighiggn4wFZzNyBUKRWLJYhpVZoTVIFBJHsNjtlMTZCgFIp7RYBgAqNmvd5sr3C6V+gOSBzhg5HW0IqRWsO0w4OxotfIV+RV42Y7G4lBJgaewSCrO+qViwPBuooHb3SOM7SSIzx06DFM89P8zve7O9mV54faIt60shsMjqvNXTjlAGBusrE4qit9tcq3wOgoAAiWGo1CoSvIACUmGMMCAACrnL4hAWGQLC0Mg6o-JqBA6tGOi1hs8hKPSRJMoe+gTsYfBcnwoFUOBdhtF+5A-mUhLqHWjJBEEXxgCAKHqGh7zYBknJPMQyyEY4LjuJ4PhAkkSJRNB8SqoJZodBk2SxLB+TFKU5RVNug4NAeQmSTgXQ9H0ibDM+KDjJM0yzOQ8wwIsfCcWsGw3AaBZiEc04kFZVz6LZbT5iOjzcmmHxfG0UR-L0CliSCEngjgkIMsW+oeU4aKskixGkb03SNPE5H8JRZKsuwplUhgdFeEEEDQuiDgoMWNI2cMBiogx-BoTlJrstoVKiuKWBuDM0J1WxPm8hmi7dhKK6yvE8q8Uq-GhZBwncJk2oMluSKGnwjamgFHAWvCVJWjaZL2o6wwum6Hp8HOHybPEC5dj6o3+n2QaTDuQ4VqOlFxgmM6poNOgaNRtFlG2A3phoWy3UuPaPTKz1lkOI5Rmhk7fSQya-WDkjMTEIOKEAA)