# ES6 Map conditional values based on key with Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this code in TypeScript:

```
type Key = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
type KeyWithToggle = Extract<Key, 'one' | 'three'>;
type KeyWithoutToggle = Exclude<Key, KeyWithToggle>;

type MergedMap = Map<KeyWithToggle, { label: string; toggleable: true }> &
  Map<KeyWithoutToggle, { label: string; toggleable?: false }>

const map: MergedMap = new Map([
  ['one', {
    label: 'label one',
    toggleable: true,
  }],
  ['two', {
    toggleable: true, // <-- expecting Error here
    label: 'label two',
  }],
  ['three', {
    label: 'label three',
    toggleable: true,
  }],
])
```

[Playground on TS Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hJQLxQOQHsB2EVQD6uAHc0d8VgALAJwmwG4AoUSWeAdQEtKAVNAcz4AbaMgCiAD2BUAhgGNgAHjggANKkzY8BarRQA+Rs2jLOlNAFdgvAcKRQJsweYAmEJfDUmuFa0IgGGJnBoAFkIKj4IZxDpMDsYsHcQUx9+PzUAbyhBaQAjCEEALigAZykODD46KGA04TzhYqlzaABfPSgAMgYoKASklIsrOohM7LyC4rKqCqqakYaIAH5igDNpQRK2vUDZTDKoAFtY4rCIqIS7LEI+2IAKAG0eqAf0LBRM596c-KLUH4KUA0Hy+8xsEEWTSoLRUz1aAF1Yb1XkQSJ9er1auDIVB1ptRqCAX8UESasQQb0EUiXuQdNh0RiicUSRNBDU6RSMVi-DjmgTKYiGPCAJQMIA)

I want strong types in case when key is `two` and value should'n have `toggleable` property as `true`.

Comment: You can't type maps like this. Just use a regular object instead.

Comment: Maps don't want to be used this way; the closest I can imagine getting is to create your own version of `Map`'s typings, similar to what's going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218).  One approach therefore looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDVaxW).  Does that fully address the question? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @katniss I need to use Map to save order of the keys. I know, i can use another variable as array with keys `const order = [] as Key[] `, but this still don't gives me necessary type checking.

@jcalz thank's for examples, seems a little big complicated to such case. I tried to use object, but have some problems with typings, [playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NdyD0m)

Comment: I misspelled myself, sorry for getting you confused, I rewrote my example [link](https://tsplay.dev/NrjY2N)

Comment: That looks like you hit the next problem after resolving the one from the question; followup questions probably belong in separate posts.  (You seem to be expecting control flow to automatically distribute over unions, but they don't, as per [ms/TS#25051](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051). This feels completely out of scope here.) Could you tell me if I've missed anything about your question as asked in my previous comment?

Comment: No, I viewed your example with writing suctom realization of Map so im my case it seems overcomplicated, thank's a lot for your attention and helping