# Generic types in classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics

I'm trying to implement generic types into classes but it turns out that I'm lacking understanding of what you can and cannot do with generics.

Hopefully someone can help me with this!

#### What I want

I have created a class which is supposed to register tasks and run them later by id. A `taskObject` consists of `taskId: string` and a callback function `callback: <R>(...args: any) => R`. Tasks will be registered when instantiating the class.

The idea is that I have type information about the return type of the callback function **for each individual task**.

So `taskId` is a **literal type** and `callback` ist supposed to be **an arbitrary function** for which I want to **infer the return type** and make this return type accessible within my class.

#### The code

```js
type Task<T extends string, V extends <R>(...args: any) => R> = {
  taskId: T
  callback: V // <-- I would like this resolved
}

class Taskmanager<T extends string, V extends <R>(...args: any) => R> {

  private callbacks = new Map<T, V>();

  public constructor(tasks: Task<T,V>[]) {
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      this.callbacks.set(task.taskId, task.callback);
    });
  }

  public runCallback(taskId: T) {
    return this.callbacks.get(taskId)?();
  }
}
```

This kind of does the first step → I have type hints for all registered `taskIds`.

```js
const tm = new Taskmanager([
  {
    taskId: "hello",
    callback: () => "world" // <-- TS error: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'R'
  },
  {
    taskId: "circle",
    callback: () => 360 // <-- TS error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'R'
  }
]);

// I'm now getting type hints for `taskId` → "hello" | "circle"
const resHello = tm.runCallback("hello"); // <-- I would like: typeof resHello === "string" --> true
const resCircle = tm.runCallback("hello"); // <-- I would like: typeof resCircle === "number" --> true
```

Here's a [TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=37&pln=21&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwSgWACcBLXAcwBooA1DbPQqFAJQD4AKAOn7ikqCAFxQ4uEAEooAXk5QucqAG8AUFCjBESAJL4xMDVADGcADbmARnBNIxjAPSO2AWldRdUAO4B7AK7m+FDm5EjQwAAW5ESkEAi+5gBuEPhqAL5qaibmiETwyAC2EnBUEKRoTDgERCQU1HSMWNWsHDz8vILCYhLScgpK6sZgFElwOKYW1rZIRLJQuBDeUACycGBojTxSANxZmmD+VqEmpr64df4mwL6k3NrIorA6m-ScANoAujLqmpoPs14ADNbgBRWyRe46fqqYx-LTRBC8MyWGx2JEICDAKHIXgA-R0AHIqZopC7OFQdLkzSZYZHE5QUj+XAAYRJMxxegMsB+FLiwH8pFwCJixNRMyRZWx+Pw1MpGSyJnOJC0hWUi2WBSQxVwpXK3Hexl+fxlYgARJEIJZfGaaBSUdM7GJuDJ5FAzX5SEEzVBnG4PDAAMoYUikW6GcDQADkdUoVCjUBiC18wHECAQ5CouuOEV8WkjUCj7CjxnSds0xv+On05pM5FIOQgtvt7KdUBdMIAzAA2AAMvpcKHcsGD5TDpAjkELuH8hSs5QTSdwKbTGazcBzWjzoCnRZLNLU3z2aj9uijauXyylwDj+an0VwwCIINIUAABjK31BAEmE7st1p9AAfd06wbcwm2yZVUziOZVV4JlWVbJBuAtK1zBtXYgA)

Which gives me the expected result that I'm only allowed to choose between `hello` and `circle` as parameter in `runCallback`. However, I'm getting TS errors when declaring the callback functions in the class constructor.

```
// TS Error for taskId: "hello"
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'R'.
  'R' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.
```

Is there a way to infer the return type of each callback function? Is this even possible?

I did check a couple other questions and answers here on StackOverflow but unfortunately I could not extract anything useful so far.

I apologise if this question is stupid. TS really drives me crazy sometimes...

Thank you!

Comment: ① Please [edit] your code to be a [mre]. When I paste this into my own IDE I see multiple errors, none of which you are asking about.  You might want to [test it out in the Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wRPVXm) to get a shareable version, and then paste that version back here *as plaintext* (a link is nice but not sufficient).

Comment: ② The type `<R>(...args: any) => R` is not safely implementable and likely not what you mean (it says "a function that takes any arguments and produces a return value of whatever type the caller wants", so `f<string>()` returns a `string` and `f<number>()` returns a `number`, even though both are `f()` at runtime).  You likely mean for `R` to be scoped differently.  If you [edit] to fix your example as per the previous comment I will check back to see how that can be done.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the comment! I've forgotten the `V` on the type definition for the constructor parameter `Task<T,V>[]`. Furthermore, the `callbacks` object did not throw an error in my IDE thus sorry for not cross checking agin with TS Playground. However, I've slightly changed the logic and provided a TS Playground link. NOTE: there are still the two errors from my original question.

Comment: Regarding the 2nd comment. I guess, I was not clear what I actually want. I want to register the task with any function and infer the return type of those functions (eg. `resHello` should be of type `string` in my example above). So I guess my definition of the generic function is already compromised, right?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NVrd7N) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: See prev comment ① "any generic function" in your new edit confuses me.  Surely you don't require that the function be *generic*, especially since your examples are not generic; maybe you just mean "arbitrary"?  The word "generic" has a particular meaning in TS and so unless you are using that meaning you might want to avoid the term. ② Why do you expect `runCallback()` to return `string` or `number` (I assume you don't mean `typeof string` or `typeof number` since that doesn't mean anything) when your implementation only returns the callback and does not run it?

Comment: Yes!  Thank you so much!!! Things could be so easy sometimes  Sorry for the confusion. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Please address my most recent comment and then I'll write up an answer.

Comment: Yes indeed. I've messed up the terminology here, sorry! Regarding the return type. I meant `typeof resHello === "string"` and `typeof resCircle === "number"`. I'm not sure if this is addressed wrong in my edit. However, I'll change this accordingly.

Comment: But `this.callbacks.get(taskId)` doesn't call anything, though.  Did you mean `this.callbacks.get(taskId)?.()`?  If so then you want your functions to be constrained to `() => any` and not `(...args: any) => any`.  It could look like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/Wo1n8N) perhaps. Would you make the analogous change to the question?

Comment: Yes, sorry again. I've changed that accordingly. Also I've now used `Map<T["taskId], T["callback"]>` for the Map type. Guess I could also bang (`!`) the callback call, since the callback for the `taskId: T["taskId"]` must exist (so `return this.callbacks.get(taskId)!()` should be fine, I guess).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you plan to call these callbacks with no arguments at all, you want to constrain `V` to `() => any` and not `<R>(...args: any) => R` (which is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a way that's not even possible to implement properly).  Indeed you might even just want to use `R` and then have `callback` be of type `() => R`, but I'll make the minimal change that works:

```
type Task<K extends string, V extends () => any> = {
  taskId: K
  callback: V
}
```

Now since you plan to pass in to the `Taskmanager` constructor an array of entries, we will need to make the class generic in the type `T` of the element of that array, like this:

```
class Taskmanager<const T extends Task<string, () => any>> {

  private callbacks = new Map<string, () => any>;

  public constructor(tasks: readonly T[]) {
    tasks.forEach(task => {
      this.callbacks.set(task.taskId, task.callback);
    });
  }
```

Note that I made it a [`const` type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) because we want the compiler to infer string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) for the `taskId` properties instead of just `string`.

Also note that I made `callbacks` a `Map<string, ()=>any>` instead of something more specific to `T`.  That's because `Map<K, V>` doesn't have the kind of type necessary to keep track of the relationship specific keys and specific values.  A `Map<K, V>` is like a dictionary where all values are of type `V`.  If you need something else with `Map` you can try to write your own types for it, as in [Typescript: How can I make entries in an ES6 Map based on an object key/value type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218), but that's probably overkill here.  We'll use `() => any` and then just be careful when we implement `runCallback()`.

Which looks like this:

```
  public runCallback<K extends T["taskId"]>(taskId: K):
    ReturnType<Extract<T, { taskId: K }>["callback"]> {
    return this.callbacks.get(taskId)!();
  }
}
```

This is a fairly complicated call signature, but it's necessary to do something like this since `T` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of subtypes of `Task<string, ()=>any>`.  So we want to constrain `K` to the union of `taskId` properties of `T`, and then the return type requires that we [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) from the union the member whose `taskId` property is of type `K`, get its `callback` property, and get the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) of that.  The implementation needs to use a [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) to convince the compiler that `get()` will not return `undefined`.  And we just need to be careful, since the compiler sees the return type as `any` which is assignable to anything.  We could have written `this.callbacks.get(taskId+"oops")!();` and it would have compiled.

---

Anyway, let's test it out:

```
const tm = new Taskmanager([
  {
    taskId: "hello",
    callback: () => "world"
  },
  {
    taskId: "circle",
    callback: () => 360
  }
]);
/* const tm: Taskmanager<{
    readonly taskId: "hello";
    readonly callback: () => string;
} | {
    readonly taskId: "circle";
    readonly callback: () => number;
}> */

const res = tm.runCallback("hello");
// const res: string
console.log(res.toUpperCase()) // "WORLD"
```

Looks good.  The constructor call is accepted, and the type of `tm` encodes enough information about the constructor argument to compute the right type for `tm.runCallback("hello")`, which is `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNYB4DSUIA9gQHYAmCUCwATgJZ4DmANFAGqY75FQAUAlFALwB8UOHhACeUAN4BYAFBQowREgCSBAFxQ0MuQGM4AGz0AjONqTqGMgL4yZ2vYmLxkAWyFxqEMim0B7PKVhmXEJHRRRSShp6Ll4BIREBKWktKDBKADc4XChdA2NTYjE8CAB3KABZODBw8io6Dm5+QWE+AG4bWVSAV0M9Cm0cvwiu7WAfMnYFZAR1Mgg4Aj89EFgAbQBdbiS5OSmkBAA6ADNxgFETAAtJxViJFJ35C4pD3KMTfYOECGBr5AO9lT0PYHV75JCcdqdOSWCEpazJTpgHp9AZkLp4ADC+jepnQQVYjlWACIAQQies+L9lGoNJxVPcoAAlb5dMh4GDgCAoU44MgmYAoGD0cTyRQqdQYSx8Ymg97kxIMubAVl4R7PEHYsGHDw-UmcACEXEh0KsHV8-mA8mcvCgxTKTiQrjw7k87FWKW2O1J6iJFwgBh8RNoDNlpnUMSaRJK4z0ZLhwc6nt2YppRO0FDIdggQZDmve4caAgAzAA2AAMcJkm0hAHoAFSDC1W9QOp0urxJqBzBZLFbeqC+-16QPGnbdxZ4ZY5PNhhq3CJ1SGWKAAHzuUK78wnU-7aYzWaJo7k49707y+bnTTwXWchk8S4EdZrZqGlrmhStBzRmJnSHYg4DIlYWkGsa0bAJ33UBcaFsIYfD0CADmHah2Hff4fAAVTASAyCxL4uG4UCBwAdQAeUZAAZAARIkZCAA)

Comment: Hey @jcalz! Thanks again for helping out! I now have a follow up question which I'm - although trying hard - not able to solve... Would you mind and have a look? Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77425637/generic-typing-of-callback-functions-in-classes?noredirect=1#comment136497756_77425637). Thanks! 