# Generic typing of callback functions in classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, typescript-generics

This is a follow up from my last post [Generic types in classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77423176/generic-types-in-classes/77423681#77423681) which has been perfectly answered by [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz). Since playing around with this solution, I highly doubt my understanding of Typescript in general. I simply can't get my head around of what is going on and why certain things "are not working".

However, I recently wanted to know how I could achieve a typed mapping of `taskIds` to their `callback` back functions and get a typed result. See here. I have now set up another minimal example
which is available on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=67&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgZwNYB4ZQgD2BAdgEwSgWACcBLXAcwD4oBeKAbwCgopz8AuWAbjagBjOABsRAIziCkPABRgA-Dzi4QAGigA3JcygBtAAodcsALrLVUAL4BKBnRUh+V-iwD0bqAFofvv-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-w1A0jV1NlP3AyCtEtGCTxXe1UJdQV3XlL0Vh9VFSGfANU2DLYw2AqNhR4nhcC6UpxCyFYgA):

```js
type Task<T extends string> = {
  id: T;
  callback: (p?: any, v?: { [P in T]: any }) => any;
};

// ----------------------
// Test 1
// ----------------------
class InferCallbackParams<const T extends string> {

  public constructor(p: Task<T>[]) {}

  public run<K extends T>(id: K): ReturnType<Extract<Task<K>, {id: K}>["callback"]> {}

}

const t1 = new InferCallbackParams([
  {
    id: "one",
    callback: (p, v) => {
      // v?: { one: any; two: any }
      return 1;
    },
  },
  {
    id: "two",
    callback: (p, v) => {
      return "string";
    }
  }
]);

const r1 = t1.run("one")
// r1: any 


// ----------------------
// Test 2
// ----------------------
class InferCallbackReturnType<const T extends Task<string>> {

  public constructor(p: T[]) {}

  public run<K extends T["id"]>(id: K): ReturnType<Extract<T, {id: K}>["callback"]> {
    return "" as any
  }

}

const t2 = new InferCallbackReturnType([
  {
    id: "one",
    callback: (p, v) => {
      // v?: { [x: string]: any }
      return 1;
    },
  },
  {
    id: "two",
    callback: (p, v) => {
      return "string";
    }
  }
]);

const r2 = t2.run("one")
// r2: number
```

##### What I would like to achieve

I found that, depending on how I define the generic type of the class, I can either have

- infer the types for `v` in the `callback` parameters and make them available when adding to the class constructor - **Test 1**, OR
- infer the return types from the `callback` functions I have declared in the class constructor and thus have the return types available as type hints when executing `run()` - **Test 2**

So I guess when declaring `const T extends Task<string>`, I will only map over `id` and assign `string` to the `callback` parameter `v` (instead of mapping again). If I do `const T extends string` and have `Task<T>[]` as the parameter type for the class constructor, I map over T but can only infer `any` as this is defined in type `Task`.

Is there a way of having both? Infer for `v` and infer the return type of `callback` when constructing the class?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does `T` need to be a type parameter? Also I'd write `S` instead of `T["taskId"]`

Comment: Hey @Bergi! Thanks for the answer. Sorry, I do not really understand: what do you mean with "T as type parameter"? I could also completely skip `S` since I need to infer the string literal types for `taskId` (so I could have `<const T<string, Callback<string>>>`) but I imagine that I somehow have to define something extra here in order to infer the string literals within the callback parameter definition.

Comment: Oh I missed that you're trying to extract the concrete return types from `T`, nevermind.

Comment: For your main question: no, the compiler is not clever enough to follow your impl logic to infer those types.  You'll need a type assertion somewhere, possibly [a bit earlier](https://tsplay.dev/WPMQJw) but it's not avoidable.  Does that fully address the question (I'm ignoring the "totally optional" bit because question posts should ask a single question, not multiple)?  If so I could write up an answer explaining the limitation that generic conditional types are opaque to the compiler.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! I already thought that this might be the case. I think it does address my question. How would I define such a type assertion?

Comment: You've already done it (but you're calling it "casting" which is a potentially misleading term; TS *type assertions* are, at best, "reinterpret casts" which just change how the type checker interprets the type.  They have none of the other behavior type coercion behavior people normally mean with "cast").  As I showed [in this link](https://tsplay.dev/WPMQJw) you can maybe more the type assertion earlier, but it's still there.  If that makes sense I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.  Or is there still a disconnect somewhere?

Comment: _you're calling it "casting"_  > Good point I never thought about it this way before! Sorry, haven't seen what you have addressed in the link earlier. The type assertion for `results` in  `run()` was not my main concern but thanks for clearing it up! What I really want is typescript to infer my `v` parameter in the callback function. Here's a [link](https://t.ly/1Z1s9) to better explain. I can have either the inferred params or the inferred return type but not both.

Comment: Uh oh, are you saying that the "`// Is there a better way than casting the return type?`" was a *third* question?  I'm afraid that I looked at the wrong question in there.  Please, for clarity, [edit] the post so there is a single well-defined question, without ancillary/bonus questions.  I'll take another look when I get a chance.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the confusion! I've updated my question and linked the minimal example. Hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Okay, this is probably just a case of [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599); you need to infer your callback params contextually from the generics *and vice versa*, so there's a circularity here that the compiler breaks instead of resolving.  Any fix I can come up with is clunky in some way, so I don't know what to tell you to do.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I've tried to find out what I should try to do but do not really understand. So if you could hint me into a direction (maybe a rough example of how you would approach this) would be awesome!