# What's the difference between Map and Record

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I don't quite get what the difference between Map and Record in Typescript is.

The only comparison I found was

> A very useful built-in type introduced by Typescript 2.1 is Record: it allows you to create a typed map and is great for creating composite interfaces.

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/advanced-typescript-types-with-examples-1d144e4eda9e,

but typing Maps like this:

```js
const testMap = new Map<number, string>();
```

also works, so I don't really understand the difference.

Comment: `Record` is JavaScript's Object used as a map (key-value pair). As for the difference between `Map` and Object, see [Map vs Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript)