# Is there a better way to loop through a large array to find the number of each item?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have a JSON file with over 20k entries with the names of different tracks on Spotify. I was trying to count the number of times each song has been played by a specific artist.

```
function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    nfPlays.push(count)
    return count;
}
nfSongs2 = []
nfSongs = []
nfPlays = []

for(var i = 0; i < dta.length; i++) {
  if(dta[i].artistName === "NF") {
    nfSongs.push(dta[i].trackName)
  }
}
for(var i = 0; i < dta.length; i++) {
  if(nfSongs2.indexOf(dta[i].trackName) === -1 && dta[i].artistName === "NF") {
    nfSongs2.push(dta[i].trackName)
  }
}

for(var i = 0; i < nfSongs2.length; i++) {
  console.log(`${nfSongs2[i]} has ${countInArray(nfSongs, nfSongs2[i])} plays`)

}

console.log(countInArray(nfSongs, "WHY"))

console.log(nfPlays)
console.log(nfSongs2)
console.log(nfSongs)
```

That's currently my code. Basically what it does is loop through the `dta` array and grab all the entries by NF (specifically the track names) which includes the duplicates, and then it does that again but this time, only grabbing unique names. Then I run `countInArray` on all the unique names of the tracks which will grab the number of plays and push it to the `nfPlays` array.

Not especially complicated and it does work. I was wondering if there is a better, shorter way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Map which is presents a faster lookup than an array (indexOf)

```js
const dta = [
  { trackName:'a', artistName:'NF' },
  { trackName:'a', artistName:'NF' },
  { trackName:'b', artistName:'NF' },
  { trackName:'b', artistName:'other' },
]
const trackNameToCount = dta.reduce((m, track) => {
  if (track.artistName === 'NF') {
    const n = m.get(track.trackName) || 0
    m.set(track.trackName, n+1)
  }
  return m
}, new Map())

;[...trackNameToCount.entries()].forEach(([name, count]) => {
  console.log(`${name} played ${count} times`)
})
```

Comment: Could the values be pushed to an array?

Comment: I don't know to which values you refer to, but yes they can be pushed to an array

Comment: @Steve [no](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). not supported for IE. use a polyfill or the built in Object ({}) if need be

Comment: @grodzi What advantage do you see using maps over built in objects?

Comment: @steve tldr Here it is mainly just semantics. There's a lot of more objective [content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript). To me though I just like Map.prototype.has. I like less and less typing Object(stuff)...which is lengthy (be it keys, values, entries, hasOwnProperty, ..). On the same hand the main drawback of Map is that it is verbose for incrementing stuff. Hopefully [upsert](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-upsert) or something else may come, and at least we are aware that it is a bit cumbersome. Perf is nice to have but not relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the `filter` method. For example:

```
function countInArray(array, what) {
    const foundItems = array.filter(value => value === what);
    nfPlays.push(foundItems.length)
    return foundItems.length;
}
```

Or

```
const foundTracks = dta.filter(track => track.artistName === "NF");
```

[Background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understand what you're doing.  I'd suggest using the object type to handle duplicates.  Something like this?

```js
dta = [
  {trackName: "dog", artistName: "NF"},
  {trackName: "dog", artistName: "mack"},
  {trackName: "dog", artistName: "NF"},
  {trackName: "cat", artistName: "fred"},
  {trackName: "mouse", artistName: "NF"},
]

nfsongs = {}

dta.forEach(item => {
    if (item.artistName==="NF") {
        if (item.trackName in nfsongs) {
            nfsongs[item.trackName]++;
        } else {
            nfsongs[item.trackName]=1;
        }
    }
})

for (key in nfsongs) {
    console.log(`${key} has ${nfsongs[key]} plays`)
}
```