# How to Push a map into a list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So what I am trying to do is take data from a form and push it into my list as a map. It currently says

> Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

```
express = require("express");
app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(express.static("public"));
var imagedata = [
    {url: "...", description: "..."},
    {url: "...", description: "..."}
];
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home.ejs", {imagedata: imagedata});
});
app.post("/post", function(req, req){
    var NewPost = req.body.url;
    var Description = req.body.description;
    imagedata.push({url: NewPost, description: Description});
    res.redirect("/");

});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: so what's your problem ?

Comment: Do you mean object when you say map?

Comment: Sorry, what I am trying to do is push the NewPost variable and Description variable into the image data list as a map. So it would be like what is currently in the image data list.

Comment: It currently says url is undefined

Comment: It doesn't say `url` is undefined, it says `req.body` is undefined.

Comment: You have a typo: `(req, req)` should be `(req, res)`

Comment: You are right, my error was the typo. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's saying `req.body` is undefined because you defined both the request and response as `req`

Change `app.post("/post", function(req, req)` to `app.post("/post", function(req, res)`

Comment: The question should just be closed as a typo, no need to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing the client-side code (the form) I don't really see anything wrong with the code. Try adding `console.log` to `/post`:

```
express = require("express");
app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(express.static("public"));
var imagedata = [
    {url: "...", description: "..."},
    {url: "...", description: "..."}
];
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home.ejs", {imagedata: imagedata});
});
app.post("/post", function(req, req){
    var NewPost = req.body.url;
    var Description = req.body.description;

    console.log("NewPost:", NewPost, "NewDescription:", Description);

    imagedata.push({url: NewPost, description: Description});

    console.log("imagedata:", imagedata);

    res.redirect("/");

});
```

to see what data is being given and what has happened to `imagedata`.

Comment: It's getting an error on the assignment to `NewPost`. It will never get to the `console.log()` line.

Comment: Whats the error? Please include it in your question

Comment: It's in the beginning of the question: "Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"

Comment: The only place where it tries to read the property `url` is in `req.body.url`, so that implies that `req.body` is undefined.

Comment: ohhh, ok sorry about that can we see the HTML form?

Comment: BTW, it's not my question.

Comment: Also, at the first line, try adding `console.log(req.body)` to see the full body.

Comment: We know that will say `undefined`. If you want to log something, try `console.log(req)`. That will show a `Result` object instead of a `Request` object, because of the typo.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned the question is not really clear but maybe this is what you are looking for although i don't really see the use case for using map instead of an object in this instance. see this post on when to use a map [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18541990/12219726)

```
express = require("express");
app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(express.static("public"));
var imagedata = [
    {url: "...", description: "..."},
    {url: "...", description: "..."}
];
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("home.ejs", {imagedata: imagedata});
});
app.post("/post", function(req, req){
    var NewPost = req.body.url;
    var Description = req.body.description;
    let map = new Map() 
    map.set('url', NewPost).set('description', Description)
    imagedata.push(map);
    res.redirect("/");

});
```

Comment: He's not using a map. He's just using the word "map" to mean "object".

Comment: Changing from an object to a map won't fix the error he's getting. It was just a typo in a variable name.