# what is the difference between { [k: string]: string } and Map<string, string>

Tags: javascript, typescript

I understand the normal `Map<string, string>` format. But i have seen some people use `{ [k: string]: string }` for the same use case?

Are they same or different? i cannot find a proper documentation regarding it's use cases.

is it possible to convert one to another?

Does it have to do something with the object de-structuring ?

Answer (score 4):

In a basic sense, `{ [k: string]: string }` is for an object, and `Map<string, string>` is for a Javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) primitive, which is not exactly the same.

For example, you could do `Map<object, string>`, because a Map can use an object as a key.  However, `{ [k: object]: string }` immediately throws an error, because javascript objects cannot use objects as their keys.

This does not have to do with destructuring, but rather with the [difference between a standard javascript Object and a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript).  I'm not sure what you mean when you say you've seen them used interchangeably, as [this typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiMEMwBVzQLyyQHgM7ACcBLAOwHMAaKfY8gPgCgHRJYQB5AIwCsIBjYKlaYA3lADaAawggAXDVJkAurOqFFUAL5M+AexL4owABaLVcRCjRRRDKEdPlVAchOLnDbQz0HgUALbwSOYcPPyC1pgkEADuWGAAFACUDIGWAHS4EMAJAERu5LlU+Y5kuUlAA) throws an error when mixing them up.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice wut? No, an object.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Ummm...no?  `{ [key: type]: type }` is how we notate an object's key's type in typescript....in this case, `[]` is not an array, but a dynamically accessed object key.

Comment: Oh gotcya...the brackets confused me there.

Comment: so saying `{}` and `{abc: test }` would be same? i mean if i defined something as types as `{ [k:string]:string}` , could i defined an empty one as  `let abc = {}`. Since it's an object?

Comment: Yes that's fine, `{ [k:string]: string }` allows for empty objects, so long as any entries in that object that occur have string values.  [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAK2QG8AoZZAbQGsIBPALmQGcwpQBzAXSdfZA4BuUgF9SpBOhCtkmOvgJMM2BcgC8JMaTkKAdAAsIAGyPp1yAOSGT6C9vmFdHdOgAmeOig0AmIA)

Comment: i am not sure, i have one object property of such type but when de-structuring it back to some object gives me `undefined`

Comment: `let { attachments } = resource.current.aws.policies.attachments;
const policies = {};
console.log(resource.current)
console.log("attachments", attachments);`  output is : `e (object) and attachments as {}` while second line shows `undefined`.

Comment: Its hard to say exactly is going on in your specific use case, but are you sure you want `let { attachments } = resource.current.aws.policies.attachments`?  Shouldn't that be `let { attachments } = resource.current.aws.policies`?