# How are dictionaries and maps are different? Which can be more usable?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, maps

I want to know the difference between maps and dictionaries. Previously, I used dictionaries but it didn't give expected results and is very difficult. So I switched to maps, then the corresponding operations become easier.

Comment: Is this question asked in context of a specific programming language or it's about a common concept of map and dictionary?

Comment: Yes it is specific to javascript

Comment: In JS terminology, there are no 'dictionaries' but objects. Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map vs Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript)