# 2 Sum algorithm explantion?

Tags: javascript

I am a noobie in JavaScript algorithm and cannot understand this optimal solution of the 2-sum

```
function twoNumberSum(array, target) {
    const nums = {};
    for (const num of array) {
        const potentialMatch = target - num;
        console.log('potential', potentialMatch);
        if (potentialMatch in nums) {
            return [potentialMatch, num]
        } else {
            nums[num] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `nums[num] = true;` adds a property (`true`) to the `nums` object. `num` becomes the key, which means `potential in nums` will be true if the currently sought 2nd number is a key of the `nums` object. It's basically a stupid and unreadable way to keep track of a list of numbers. Here's a readable version: https://jsfiddle.net/xmg8ejcr/

Comment: Although this explanation is for Python, the code is very similar. https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-implement-the-two-sum-problem-in-python

Comment: @ChrisG A `Set` might be more readable still, and possibly more performant :)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yeah, who knows, maybe even object keys turn out the be the most performant solution :) Still a bad way to teach newbies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the 2-sum problem basically says "find two numbers in an array that sum to the given target, and return their index". Let's walk through this code and talk about what's happening.

First, we start the function; I'm going to assume this makes sense (a function that's called `twoNumberSum` that takes in two arguments; namely, `array` and `target`) - note that in JS, we don't annotate types, so there is no return type

Now, first thing we do is create a new object called `nums`. In JS, objects are effectively hash maps (with some very important differences - see my note below); they store a key and a corresponding value. In JS, a key can be any string or number

Next, we start our iteration. If we do `for (const a of b)`, and `b` is an array, this iterates over all the values of the array, with each iteration having that value stored in `a`.

Next, we subtract our current value from the target. Then comes the key line: `if (potentialMatch in nums)`. The `in` keyword checks for the existence of a key: `'hello' in obj` returns true if `obj` has the key `'hello'`.

In this case, if we find this potential match, then that means we have found another number that is equal to `target - num`, which of course means we've found the other partner for our sum! So in this case, we simply return the two numbers. If, on the other hand, we do *not* find this `potentialMatch`, that means we need to keep looking. But we do want to remember we've seen this number - thus, we add it as a key by doing `nums[num] = true` (this creates a new key-value pair; namely the key is `num` and the value is `true`).

As one of the comments explained, this is just trying to keep track of a list of numbers; however, the author is trying to be clever by using a Hash Table instead of a normal array. This way, lookups are O(1) instead of O(n). For eyes not used to JS semantics, another way of explaining this code is that we build up a `Map` of the numbers, and then we check that map for our target value.

I mentioned earlier that using objects as hash tables isn't the best idea; this is because if you aren't careful, if you use user-provided keys, you can accidentally mess with what's called the Prototype Chain. This is beyond this discussion, but a better way forward would be to use a `Set`:

```js
function twoNumberSum(array, target) {
// Create a new Hash Set. Sets take in an iterable, so we could
// Do it this way. But to remain as close to your original solution
// as possible, we won't for now, and instead populate it as we go
// const nums = new Set(array);

const nums = new Set();
for (const num of array) {
  const potentialMatch = target - num;
  if (nums.has(potentialMatch)) {
    return [potentialMatch, num];
  } else {
    nums.add(num);
  }
}
```

Sometimes, the problem instead asks for you to return the *indices*; using a Map instead makes this relatively trivial. Just store the index as the value and you're good to go!

```js
function twoNumberSum(array, target) {
// Create the new map instead

const nums = new Map();
for (let n = 0; n < array.length; ++n) {
  const potentialMatch = target - array[n];
  if (nums.has(potentialMatch)) {
    return [nums.get(potentialMatch), n];
  } else {
    nums.set(array[n], n);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you use .has or .get instead of .includes or .find?

Comment: also some people say object is completely fine

Comment: `.includes` is only for an array; See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map for the `Set` and `Map` docs, respectively.

Using Object can be a problem for Security; see this other SO answer for a really detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37994079/5250021

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain to you what it's all is working-.

```
function twoNumberSum(array, target) {

    // This is and object in Javascript
    const nums = {};

    for (const num of array) { // This is for of loop which iterates the array.
        //For of Doc - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

        // Here's its calculating the potential.
        const potentialMatch = target - num;
        console.log('potential - ' + potentialMatch);

        /**
         * Nowhere `in` is used which check if any property exists in an object or not.
         * in Usage - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in
         * 
         * It checks whether potential exists in the `nums` object, If exist it returns the array
         *   with potentialMatch and num to which it is matched.
         * 
         * If the number is not there in nums object. It's setting there in else block 
         * to match in net iteration.
         */
        if (potentialMatch in nums) {
            return [potentialMatch, num]
        } else {
            nums[num] = true;
            /**
             * It forms an object when the potential match doesn't exist in nums for checking in the next iteration
             * {
             *      1: true,
             *      2: true
             * }
             */
        }
        console.log(nums)
    }
}

console.log(twoNumberSum([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 3))
```

You can also [Run it from JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wuceyemovu/edit?js,console)