# Do javascript/react have double arrow operator inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have array like this:

```
const arr2 = [
    one => {
      'Hello';
    },
    two => {
      'Answer';
    },
    three => {
      'LOREM IPSUM';
    },
  ];
```

If javascript have arrow operator inside array then how can i push value at one or at two.

Comment: This is an array of arrow functions. If you want something like PHP's arrays, that's not at all the same.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "how can i push value at one or at two"?
Do you mean call the first or second arrow function inside the array while passing it argument(s)?

Comment: PHP's associative array is JavaScript object.

Comment: if your goal is to create key-value pairs, you could use JavaScript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as well. Maps have more features than [JS Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr2 = [
    one => {
      'Hello';
    },
    two => {
      'Answer';
    },
    three => {
      'LOREM IPSUM';
    },
  ];
```

The one above is basically an array of arrow functions.

so if you do `arr2[0]` it will print

```
one => {
      'Hello';
    }
```

If you wanna do normal push and pop, you can do the same as what you do with arrays in JS

But by your question of double arrow operator , im assuming you wanna have to change values at particular index.

You can always do by `arr2[1] = someFunc` you wanna assign

Update:

this is what i did and this is the console.log for the same:

```
const arr2 = [
    one => {
      'Hello';
    },
    two => {
      'Answer';
    },
    three => {
      'LOREM IPSUM';
    },
  ];
  
  arr2.push("hey")
  arr2[1] = "what is this even"
  
  console.log(arr2)

/** [one => {
    'Hello';
  }, "what is this even", three => {
    'LOREM IPSUM';
  }, "hey"] **/
```

Hope it clears :)

Do let me know in case if any concerns

Comment: Yes you are right. I want to change value at particular index.
If i push value in array then it replace the arrow function with value. I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @CopyPaste please check the above updated answer

Comment: How can i change value inside given function. 
```const arr2 = [
      one => {
      'Hello';   // change value here
    },
 ];
```

Comment: arr2[0] = one => {"whaat"}