# How to obtain values from Array in JS in an optimal way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance, loops

I need to obtain a few values from a MAP in JS based on its id ("codi" in the object).

My array is something like this but bigger:

```
0: {codi: '291', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres 2010 ', check: true}
1: {codi: '292', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres < 2010 ', check: true}
2: {codi: '293', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres ', check: true}
3: {codi: '294', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres 2013  ', check: true}
4: {codi: '295', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres 2014 ', check: true}
5: {codi: '296', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC  ', check: true}
6: {codi: '297', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P5 ', check: true}
7: {codi: '298', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P15 ', check: true}
8: {codi: '299', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC DIAGONAL ', check: true}
```

Currently I am working on a simple loop, I iterate an when my variable is equals to the "codi" and return the entry.

```
function obtenerSubgrupo(codi) {
    for(j = 0; j < Object.keys(listaSubgrupo).length; j++) {
        if (codi == listaSubgrupo[i].codi) {
                return listaSubgrupo[i];
        }
    }   
}
```

How can I improve this?

I also need to extract the values that i am going to return from my main array, currently working with the info of: [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array) but any help on that will be welcome too

Thanks.

EDIT: Just to put here the links shared by Simone Rossaini in the comments as i think they are quite useful:

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/are-for-loops-better-than-arrays-filter-or-foreach-methods-f54b6880d201

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4261/0/find-vs-forof-vs-for-loop

Comment: You could use the filter method? Do something like data.filter((item) => return item.codi === '298'). Which would return an array with only one item in it (the one with codi 298, if the codi is unique of course.) 
If no matches and empty array would be returned.

Comment: For-loop is faster than filter method so your code is correct and faster, take a look [here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/are-for-loops-better-than-arrays-filter-or-foreach-methods-f54b6880d201)

Comment: Thanks, great info for both of you, that article is nuts! i will still look the filter methods because i am quite ignorant about them but i will still work with the for loop. Again, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optimal would be to invest in changing the object to a map from the `codi` to the actual value. Afterwards any other extraction would be O(1).

```js
var obj = {
  0: {codi: '291', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres 2010 ', check: true},
  1: {codi: '292', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres < 2010 ', check: true},
  2: {codi: '293', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres ', check: true},
  3: {codi: '294', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres 2013  ', check: true},
  4: {codi: '295', literal: 'MEDIFIATC Progres 2014 ', check: true},
  5: {codi: '296', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC  ', check: true},
  6: {codi: '297', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P5 ', check: true},
  7: {codi: '298', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P15 ', check: true},
  8: {codi: '299', literal: 'MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC DIAGONAL ', check: true}
}

// turning the input into an array
// skip if already an array
var arr = Object.values(obj)

var result = arr.reduce(function(agg,item) {
  agg[item.codi] = item;
  return agg;
}, {})

console.log(result);
// now you can:
console.log(result["294"]);
```

Comment: I will try to work in this direction, i have to iterate a lot in this array so it´s definetly worth it

Comment: The original data is an array not an object.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the optimal solution if you have to iterate a lot in the array.

Answer (score 3):

By "optimal" if you mean the most performant you should do benchmarks, and even then there can be differences in different browsers and run-time environments.

You can use more recent array methods in JS like `find`, keep in mind that `filter` will be definitively slower because it keeps iterating even when it finds the first match because searching for more matches.

```
item = listaSubgrupo.find(i => i.codi === codi)
```

Comment: Seems like for-loop is faster then all method (same for find) [Bench](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/4261/0/find-vs-forof-vs-for-loop)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks for the link, so the `for ... of` is the fastest according to this bench, right? can this website test on different browsers as well?

Comment: `For.. of` is faster yes, 
For browsers I think you have to open them one by one even though I honestly don't think there are big differences.

Comment: Yes, `for..of` is faster since it doesn't need to create a callback and a new context for each iteration. It's independent of the used method: as much as there's a callback it will be slower

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `codi` values are unique convert the array to [a Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or an object using the `codi` value as the key. It makes it simple to get at the data then.

[This old question/set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript) re the value of which structure to use will be very helpful on deciding which to use.

Map:

```js
const arr=[{codi:"291",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres 2010 ",check:!0},{codi:"292",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres < 2010 ",check:!0},{codi:"293",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres ",check:!0},{codi:"294",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres 2013  ",check:!0},{codi:"295",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres 2014 ",check:!0},{codi:"296",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC  ",check:!0},{codi:"297",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P5 ",check:!0},{codi:"298",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P15 ",check:!0},{codi:"299",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC DIAGONAL ",check:!0}];

const map = new Map();

for (const obj of arr) {
  map.set(obj.codi, obj);
}

console.log(map.get('298'));
```

Object:

```js
const arr=[{codi:"291",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres 2010 ",check:!0},{codi:"292",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres < 2010 ",check:!0},{codi:"293",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres ",check:!0},{codi:"294",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres 2013  ",check:!0},{codi:"295",literal:"MEDIFIATC Progres 2014 ",check:!0},{codi:"296",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC  ",check:!0},{codi:"297",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P5 ",check:!0},{codi:"298",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC P15 ",check:!0},{codi:"299",literal:"MEDIFIATC MEDIFIATC DIAGONAL ",check:!0}];

const out = {};

for (const obj of arr) {
  out[obj.codi] = obj;
}

console.log(out['298']);
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try to use array.filter or array.find, see more here > https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp and > https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp
you can write it inside your array.map function by using if function to filter them.

Comment: It is an object, so it needs more than array.filter or array.find