# I want to count the frequency of the number in array,but it's wrong when i use javascript Map()

Tags: javascript

```
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6];
let map=new Map();
arr.forEach((n)=>{
    map.set(n,map.get(n)+1);
});
for(let [k,v] of map){
    console.log(k,v);
}
```

I want to count the frequency of the number in array,but it is wrong.When i debug in console,the value of map is Nan.

[the result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49M1q.png)

Can i get some suggestions?

Comment: `map.set(n,(map.get(n)??0)+1);` - so the first get returns `0` not `undefined` - you can also use `||` instead of `??`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `map.get(n)||0`, because the initial value for the map is `undefined`, not `0`

```js
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6];
let map=new Map();
arr.forEach((n)=>{
    map.set(n,(map.get(n)||0)+1);
});
for(let [k,v] of map){
    console.log(k,v);
}
```

Comment: i didn't know `Map` exists in javascript. i always use `Object` to handle things. today i learned something new.

Comment: you don't have answer this, but do you know any cases that `Map` is better to use than `Object`? example would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: They are very similar. This answers it partially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18541990/16634738.