# Is there a better way of storing in-memory data instead of using arrays and index-based functions in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, data-structures

I am trying to understand whether there is a better way of storing and accessing data instead of using Array index-based calls.

For example:

```js
export interface EntityInterface {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export class ClassName {
    entities: EntityInterface[] = [];

    temporaryIndex: number = 0;

    createEntity(name: string, age: number) {
        const temporaryId = ++this.temporaryIndex;

        this.entities.push({
            id: temporaryId,
            name: name,
            age: age
        });
    }

    getEntityById(id: number): number | undefined {
        const entityIndex = this.entities.findIndex((entity) => entity.id === id);
        if (entityIndex === -1) {
            return;
        }

        return entityIndex;
    }

    getEntityName(id: number): string | undefined {
        const index = this.getEntityById(id);
        if (! index) {
            return;
        }

        return this.entities[index].name;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that using an external database is not necessary in this case because I do not care if we lose data once the application has shutdown.

Comment: It is actually js so you can use Map or Set.

Comment: You can also use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Does the Map allow us to have strict-typed checking of the values that are set inside the Map, such as I'm doing with the EntityInterface?

Comment: You can just store it in an object with `id` as the key, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjpovm).  That way you just look it up by `id` directly instead of doing an array find.  Does that meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: That's clear. I'm trying to understand if there's any way to get rid of `temporaryIndex` and `const temporaryId = ++this.temporaryIndex;` horrible code that I feel like could be improved. Or is that totally urelated to the question?

Comment: Furthermore, @jcalz, how is your approach compared to the Map one?

Comment: ① If you need to generate a unique id for each added object, then it's sort of unrelated to the question... an auto-incrementing variable seems fine to me.  ② `Map` vs plain objects is ‍♂️.  Both work well enough for looking things up by key.  Any performance difference is almost certainly going to be small compared to doing a find on an array. ⊛ So how would you like to proceed here?

Comment: You can create an answer, it'd be great if you could also add a Map example as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to look up a value by a numeric key in TypeScript (and therefore in JavaScript) you should probably use a data structure meant for lookups by key.

Plain [JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) behave this way automatically; in TypeScript you could give an object a numeric [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures):

```
class ClassName {
    entities: { [k: number]: EntityInterface | undefined } = {};

    temporaryIndex: number = 0;

    createEntity(name: string, age: number) {
        const temporaryId = ++this.temporaryIndex;
        this.entities[temporaryId] = {
            id: temporaryId,
            name: name,
            age: age
        };
    }

    // this is unlikely to be useful
    getEntityById(id: number): number | undefined {
        return this.entities[id] ? id : undefined
    }

    getEntityName(id: number): string | undefined {
        return this.entities[id]?.name;
    }
}
```

Or you can use a JavaScript [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), which you can tell TypeScript holds `EntityInterface` values at `number` keys:

```
class ClassName {
    entities = new Map<number, EntityInterface>()

    temporaryIndex: number = 0;

    createEntity(name: string, age: number) {
        const temporaryId = ++this.temporaryIndex;
        this.entities.set(temporaryId, {
            id: temporaryId,
            name: name,
            age: age
        });
    }

    // this is unlikely to be useful
    getEntityById(id: number): number | undefined {
        return this.entities.has(id) ? id : undefined
    }

    getEntityName(id: number): string | undefined {
        return this.entities.get(id)?.name;
    }
}
```

Both of those should behave quite similarly, especially compared to iterating through an array.  See [Map vs Object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541940/map-vs-object-in-javascript) and [the MDN documentation on `Map` vs `Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps) for help choosing between them.

And in both versions, `getEntityById(id)` is now going to either return its input or `undefined`, so it's unlikely to be useful.  You can just immediately look up `this.entities` with `id` as the key, and deal with a potentially `undefined` result.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLmGAngSXNeJZAbwChkLlgATALmRAFcBbAI2gG5zKQ5mJ6AZzBRQAcy6VkcMQIYt2ULgF9SpXv0EAHRCgAKAGzigA8qwBWEBGBJqpCI4MHIAwo8EA5PijJSpEDDBgCEF6YmQAbQBreiY2aABdenQg7DxIWF1kAB9kRhBqCBhQCGpkZWQAXhJlLm4-ZEhmLQB7KDgoXAKIAA9YhWgq5AAGOoaKBCgIOEgUzCwACg05YVEQMQAaaVl++KgASltxvwQWkGFGiGa2jtwy6oBqB7AAC2BBADom1vbOvEKepJjpRXu8PgFUsFBBFvjc-tQEkNfMCGjR6LDfncNvUUTxvLFvNjcX4ZHJSTjjrUKZRVNSKAB6emNN7Od55EAGYBRCAGLCNFrIdh5QRFRgGOnIWRgObYABCdwWaPke32u0UOXZhWKIFKR1xUzAjCgIGZYIhmChERoiIA-FQyvR8lqStQJbTjlKZVgvPxFXRlYpVchVuINU6ii69SiDUaTaDPuagiErQibR9lkCGqopLTacttFkALJwLQANWggmAZ1sOIccCcrncPp8EsTUKGOoA7shi1oADxxRRbL3pAi6AB8C32dnGGNu-16asG1VGM4ak2ms0Ci2WQhE4i2pKXByjwNO5xsc-hQye8a+Vx+8+6gIlUjvbZCHxFYAWV6xp+JJU-xwagiWJPF+AJfgwPA7YyVkV8aX2TM-HdcZGVNVlnHyTluV5flBRQRgRRgMUJU9bd5RAv1jyDQdBlycNtV1ZFowgQ1jUw8FAihD4XnrP1DjtGhkEdbpmNdSk1z8CjUm9bwaIDaAgxDdYw3EyNWOBGNOPfHjPylQS0wzN0cVzIA)